# How would i change every character in the string a different color instead of the whole string

Tags: c++, string, colors

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>

unsigned long n = 1;

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    std::string text = "I whip my hair back and forth";
    std::string wipIt = " ";
    size_t sz;
    sz = wipIt.size();
    srand(time(0));

    do{
        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int randomNumber = rand() % 15 + 1;
            Sleep(50);
            wipIt.resize (sz++,' ');
            std::cout << wipIt;
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), randomNumber);
            std::cout << text << "\n";
        }
        for(i = 10; i > 0; i--)
        {
            int randomNumber = rand() % 15 + 1;
            Sleep(50);
            wipIt.resize (sz--,' ');
            std::cout << wipIt;
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), randomNumber);
            std::cout << text << "\n";
        }
    }
    while (n != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

If I messed this post up I apologize this is only like my second post.

What would be the easiest way to make every character in the string a different color, instead of the entire string the same color.

Tidying up tips would be appreciated as well :P

EDIT: tidy'd up a little, and the random is working well, thank you all ^_^ now for the color by character?

Comment: std::srand(std::time(0)) (from <ctime>) before your first call to std::rand(). This sets a seed for the pseudo-random number generator that's reasonably random (rand() essentially just iterates over a long sequence of numbers that are expected to be distributed in a random seeming pattern. srand(seed) set's a seed for rand, time(0) is the current time in seconds since epoch (usually anyways, either way it's the current time in some metric).

Comment: tidy up tip: you're using a lot of extra braces. I sometime use extra braces to limit the lifetime of a particular variable, but here there are braces that don't do anything except mess with the indentation. I would remove those.

Comment: Using the C++11 `<random>` library, if available to you, is preferable to using `rand()`.

Comment: tidy up tip: You are mixing different styles regarding capitalization of variables. Pick a style, and stick with it ;)

Comment: `endl` both adds a new line and flushes the buffer. This can cause output performance to suffer greatly. Almost always you'll just want to write a newline: `cout << Test << '\n';`. Also `using namespace std;` is used a lot in beginning programming examples, but IMO it's better not to use it, and instead to either just qualify names: `std::cout << Test << '\n';` or to use more specific using declarations: `using std::cout; ... cout << Test;`

Comment: @bames53 I disagree here about `std::endl`. Flushing is probably desirable here, where it looks as if the output is specifically supposed to appear at intervals, with the `Sleep(50)` in between. Otherwise if the buffer is large, you could end up with several lines appearing all at once, after a longer delay than intended.

On the other hand, if you mean flush, it may be clearer to do it explicitly.

Comment: @BoBTFish Since this is the Windows console using `endl` isn't actually necessary to get the output to appear immediately and IMO it's good to get into the habit of not using `endl`. But you're right that on other platforms this application might require flushing and therefore be one of the few cases where `endl` is desirable (or `flush` as you point out, since I think you're probably right about that being clearer).

Comment: tidy up tip: you have repeated code where the only difference is whether you're incrementing or decrementing the initial spacing. I would pull the duplicated code into a function that takes the initial spacing as a parameter in order to eliminate the duplication.

Comment: Instead of doing an infinite loop by using `do { } while(n!=0);` on a variable that is always 1 it's more readable to simply use `while(true) {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does it not seem random? Well, because it isn't. Computers use pseudorandom number generators to produce seemingly random numbers which are actually well-known and determinate.

The initial state of the pseudorandom generator is called a 'seed'; you have to set it to something different every time to produce more-close-to-random results. In C, you can do it like this:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

This sets the seed to the actual time in seconds upon every call.

Answer (score 1):

In order to colorize by character you have to manually iterate through the characters of the string and set the color attribute before outputting each character.

(The below code iterates by `char`. This doesn't work for character sets that actually use multi-byte encodings. To support those you'll have to use an API to iterate over the string by actual, user perceived characters instead of by `char`.)

This code has several other changes as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>

#include <Windows.h>

void colorize(size_t spacing, std::string const &s, std::mt19937 &eng) {
    std::cout << std::string(spacing, ' ');
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(1,15);
    for (size_t i=0; i<s.size(); ++i) {
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), dist(eng));
        std::cout << s[i];
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::string text = "I whip my hair back and forth";
    int sz = 0;

    std::random_device r;
    std::seed_seq seed{r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r()};
    std::mt19937 eng(seed);

    while (true) {
        int spacing = 11 - abs(10 - sz);
        sz = (sz+1) % 20;
        Sleep(50);
        colorize(spacing, text, eng);
    }
}
```

I'm using the C++11 `<random>` library for random numbers because it's better than `rand()`. It provides many ready-made distributions and is harder to get wrong (`rand() % 15 + 1` has a slight bias even if `rand()` is high quality, which it probably is not).

I extracted the repeated code into a function to eliminate the duplication. Then I replaced the two for loops with a function that has the zigzag output that exactly matches what the two for loops were doing with sz.

I replaced the `do {} while()` infinite loop with a more readable and idiomatic `while(true){}`.

I eliminated the string variable that was being resized for the spacing in favor of constructing a temporary each iteration. This does mean there could be an allocation each iteratation instead of a simple resize (although the small string optimization will probably avoid it) but the performance is irrelevant in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a seed for your random number generator prior to first use.

An [example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/srand/) of using srand to initialize the random number generator is:

```
/* srand example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  printf ("First number: %d\n", rand() % 100);
  srand ( time(NULL) );
  printf ("Random number: %d\n", rand() % 100);
  srand ( 1 );
  printf ("Again the first number: %d\n", rand() %100);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't make references to cplusplus dot com. It is a terrible website with a lot of bad information.

Comment: Worth taking a look: [Recommended way to initialize srand?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/322938/478288)

Comment: Shahbaz Care to elaborate? I alternate between the reference at cplusplus.com and cppreference, usually I don't find that much of a difference.

Comment: @Cubic: Several years ago, some of the information there was a bit sketchy and it got a bit of a bad reputation. It looks fine these days, although I'm sure you could the odd mistake if you looked hard enough, and I expect the knee-jerk reactions every time it's referenced here will never end.

Comment: @Shahbaz is there anything wrong with this particular example, or do you just generally not like the site?