# srand (time (null)) causes compiler warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

Apologies if this question has already been answered.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main () {

srand( time(NULL) );
cout << rand();
}
```

"implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'time_t' (aka 'long') to 'unsigned int'"

Is the error message Im getting when I execute the code above. I am using xcode 4.6.1. Now when I use a different complier such as the one from codepad.org it executes perfectly fine generating what seems like random numbers so I am assuming it is an xcode issue that I need to work around?

I have JUST started programming so I am a complete beginner when it comes to this. Is there a problem with my code or is it my complier?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: its not uncommon for longs to have more precision than unsigneds.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> "implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'time_t' (aka 'long') to 'unsigned int'"

You're losing precision implicitly because `time()` returns a `long` which is larger than an `unsigned int` on your target.  In order to workaround this problem, you should explicitly cast the result (thus removing the "implicit precision loss"):

```
srand( static_cast<unsigned int>(time(nullptr)));
```

---

Given that it's now 2017, I'm editing this question to suggest that you consider the features provided by `std::chrono::*` defined in `<chrono>` as a part of C++11.  Does your favorite compiler provide C++11?  If not, it really should!

To get the current time, you should use:

```
#include <chrono>

void f() {
    const std::chrono::time_point current_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
}
```

**Why should I bother with this when `time()` works?**

IMO, just one reason is enough: clear, explicit types.   When you deal with large programs among big enough teams, knowing whether the values passed around represent time intervals or "absolute" times, and what magnitudes is critical.  With `std::chrono` you can design interfaces and data structures that are portable and skip out on the is-that-timeout-a-deadline-or-milliseconds-from-now-or-wait-was-it-seconds blues.

Comment: As this question is tagged C++: _Please_ do not use C-style casts. `srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL));` works just as well and makes your code look all nice and shiny. As a bonus, it avoids tons of potential bugs that can creep in with C-style casts...

Comment: Indeed, I carelessly assumed that this was a C question without looking at the tags.  Answer has been edited to correct the problem.

Comment: It probably used a different target, one for which there was no precision loss between `long` and `unsigned int` (the other compiler was for a 32-bit machine and this one is 64-bit, perhaps?)

Comment: I recommended codes `std::random_device rd;`~
`std::mt19937 mt(rd());`~
`std::uniform_real_distribution<double> ddist(0, 1);`~ then use `ddist(mt);` to obtain random number in c++. In my case, I use c++11.

Comment: Okay, I can now (2017++) get the current time in a different way, but how do I use that to initialize srand()?

Answer (score 18):

As mentioned by "nio", a clean workaround would be to explicitly type cast.

**Deeper explanation:**

The srand() requires an unsigned int as parameter (`srand(unsigned int)`) but time() returns a long int (`long int time()`) and this is not accepted by the srand() so in order to fix this, the compiler has to simply typecast (convert) the "long int" to "unsigned int".

BUT in your case the compiler warns you about it instead  (as the designers of the compiler thought you should be aware that's all).

So a simple

`srand( (unsigned int) time(NULL) );`

will do the trick!

(forgive me if i have done something wrong, this is my first answer on stackoverflow)

Answer (score 6):

The `srand()` function has unsigned int as a type of argument, `time_t` is `long` type. the upper 4 bytes from `long` are stripped out, but there's no problem in it.
`srand()` will randomize the `rand()` algorithm with 4 lower bytes of `time()`, so you're supplying more data than is needed.

If you get an error, try to just explicitly cast the `time_t` type to `unsigned int`:

```
srand( static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)) );
```

Another interesting thing is that if you run your program twice in the same second, you'll get the same random number, which can be sometimes undesired, that's because if you seed the `rand()` algorithm with the same data, it will generate the same random sequence. Or it can be desirable when you debug some piece of code and need to test the same behaviour again... then you simply use something like `srand(123456)`.

Comment: As this question is tagged C++: Please do not use C-style casts

Answer (score 2):

This is **not** an error. The code is valid and its meaning is well defined; if a compiler refuses to compile it, the compiler does not conform to the language definition. More likely, it's a **warning**, and it's telling you that the compiler writer thinks that you might have made a mistake. If you insist on eliminating warning messages you could add a cast, as others have suggested. I'm not a big fan of rewriting valid, meaningful code in order to satisfy some compiler writer's notion of good style; I'd turn off the warning. If you do that, though, you might overlook other places where a conversion loses data that you didn't intend.

Comment: Just because something is technically correct doesn't mean it's a good idea. Making the explicit cast shows that you're aware there's a possibility of truncation. In this case I'd prefer that to turning off a compiler warning that might save your bacon when you're more careless.

Comment: @MarkRansom - would you remove the cast on a platform where `time_t` and `unsigned` are the same size, since the reason for the cast no longer applies? Maybe conditionalize it, based on the platform? Chasing warnings can be a bottomless pit.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't conditionalize such a cast, and I wouldn't remove it if I needed to support multiple platforms. I can see it now though, someday in the future somebody will come to StackOverflow and ask "Why is this cast here when it doesn't do anything?"

Comment: @MarkRansom - one that's worse is "function doesn't return a value" for a function that returns a value out of an otherwise infinite loop but not at the end of the function; if you add a return statement at the end of the function you'll get "code has no effect" from another compiler.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>         //rand
#include <time.h>       //time

float randomizer(int VarMin, int VarMax){
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
        int range = (VarMax - VarMin);
        float rnd = VarMin + float(range*(rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0)));
return rnd;
}
```

Comment: How can i customize this function to generate random number in microsecond? With "srand((unsigned)time(NULL))", it is not possible! What is the solution?

Comment: You can use a platform-specific function like `gettimeofday` or `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime` to return the time with sub-second precision.