# generating many random numbers in bit of time

Tags: visual-c++

I am using C++ 2012. I want to use a rand() in program that must generate random values many times (100 random number for 3000 iteration) and all of these process should be done in a second or even fewer. How can i do this. I know that "srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));" must be used as a seed for rand(). But What about these tiny bit of time while the second in time() may be the same in all 3000 iteration. I know there exist "random.h" but I am a beginner and do not know how to use it.
please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Only seed your random number generator once.**

`srand()` is used to seed the C library's random number generator (`rand()`). You absolutely do not want to call `srand` repeatedly, otherwise you ruin the psuedo-random properties of the RNG.

- [Recommended way to initialize srand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322938/recommended-way-to-initialize-srand)
- [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-only-once)