# C random number

Tags: c, random

This is my code

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>


 main()
 {
    int r = rand() % 20;
    printf("%d", r);
 }
```

I want to get a random number 19 and below, but it just gives me `1` every time I compile and run it. Can someone show me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't call `srand()`.

Comment: You need to seed the random number generator, look up `srand()`. `main()` returns an `int`, by the way.

Comment: What do I put in the function?

Comment: @samir: Look at any one of the numerous "related" questions attached to this very question.

Comment: You might want to try this XKCD's solution: http://xkcd.com/221/  (Sorry, I couldn't control!!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


 int main()
 {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int r = rand() % 20;
    printf("%d", r);
 }
```

Note: Using the % is not a great way to get an even distribution.
See: [Recommended way to initialize srand?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/322938/14065) for more info.

Comment: This is hardly any better. It will print the same number many times in a row if you run it rapidly.

Comment: @R..: I think you will find I already covered that situation in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Read up about seeding the random number generator - i.e. http://linux.die.net/man/3/srand

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Turbo C++ 4.5 then put a

```
randomize();
```

before

```
int r=rand()%20;
```

It will also give your desired result.