# Duplicate output when using srand for random seed

Tags: c++, random, srand

I'm using srand (time(NULL)); to generate a random seed.

Problem is, I'm submitting 30+ identical jobs to a LINUX cluster.  If I submit them one at a time, everything is fine, but of course I prefer to use a batch job to submit all 30 at once.  Much easier and quicker.  Problem is, then several batches of the jobs all appear to access exactly the same time, and I get duplicate results! Can anyone suggest an easy solution to this?

Comment: They are probably getting the same time stamp. Is there some environment variable you can use to add to the initial seed? Such as process ID or something?

Comment: A good watch: [rand() Considered Harmful](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because [`rand()` is considered harmful](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).

Comment: @Griwes Why does that make it off-topic? It's a programming question, isn't it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recommended way to initialize srand?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322938/recommended-way-to-initialize-srand)

Answer (score 2):

Consider reading from `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom`. They have higher quality randomness than `rand()` (which is usually just a simple linear congruential generator), and `/dev/random` blocks until sufficient entropy has built up.

Comment: Or seed the generator using them...

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to seed `rand()` with either of the random devices. `rand()` is designed to rapidly produce numbers that *appear* random. Seeding it with a random device would only limit entropy.

Comment: it would avoid his problem with duplicate generator state in batch jobs. I'm not sure how seeding `rand()` with `/dev/{u}/random` would limit entropy. Could you explain it?

Comment: Sure, but it just adds another layer of complexity. Why call `rand()` at all when you already have a good source of random numbers? Seeding `rand()` with either of the devices would limit entropy because `rand()`'s output is easy to predict, even with a good input. That's just the nature of its implementation.

Comment: Correction: I might be wrong. I don't know about `rand()`'s implementation details on Linux. On other Unix(y) systems, `rand()` is usually just a simple LCG or Twister whose output becomes predictable after a certain number of iterations. If that isn't the case on Linux, seeding `rand()` with a random device's output *may* not compromise entropy significantly.

Comment: Secure output from the generator is not a requirement in the question. OP's requirement is multiple generators that produce different outputs. That can be accomplished by reading from a random device (as you suggested), or seeding `rand()` with different seeds.

Comment: I was just thinking with scale in mind. If he's submitting 30 jobs today, he could be submitting 3000 jobs tomorrow. If the period of `rand()` is 2999, he could compromise his results. My apologies if I dragged this off topic.

Comment: GLIBC's `rand` function uses an `int32_t`. Its period is going to be on the order of 2^31 (otherwise, we would have read about the vulnerability). See [`__random`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/random.c;hb=glibc-2.15#l292) in the GLIBC sources.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the new features in `<random>` in C++11. In particular std::random_device. Otherwise, a cheesy solution is to add pid to time(NULL).