# C program for generating random numbers

Tags: c

I'm writing a code that will return a random number between 5 and 20, and i'm running into a problem where it will always produce the same number over again and i can't seem to solve it.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int random = 0;

int randomnumbergen() {
srand(12345);
random = rand() % (20 - 15) + 15;
return random;
}
```

Comment: Not really a miracle - you seed the random number generator with the same value all them time!

Comment: Once you get `srand()` fixed, I think you'll still have problems with `random = rand() % (20 - 15) + 15;`.

Comment: @FoggyDay: it depends on whether the typo is in the code or the statement of the range.  IIRC, you need a `+1` in the modulo range to get the 6 numbers 15..20 (or 16 numbers from 5..20).

Comment: See also: [Recommended way to initialize `srand()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322938/recommended-way-to-initialize-srand)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you'll want to call srand() at the beginning of your program one time.

Next, you'll want to replace

```
srand(12345);
```

with

```
srand (time(NULL));
```

Comment: This will still cause the same number to be returned *if randomnumbergen() is called repeatedly in a tight loop*.

Comment: @EricJ. true, but at least a step ahead of using the same number every time.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I would argue it is worse, because a unit test for the function that does not consider the temporal factor may well show it "working", while it fails when used in a loop.  Effectively, the bug is better hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same seed each time - producing identical results. You need to not hardcode it.

Comment: But removing the call to `srand()` also leaves the results deterministic, albeit with a different sequence.  You need to call `srand()` with a different number each time.  Consider reading a random number from `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: The observation is correct, the proposed solution is system specific.

Comment: @EricJ. The suggested solution works on most modern variants of Unix (Mac OS X, Linux I've tested this year; I think it works on Solaris, but I've not used it for a couple of years now - I'm not sure about HP-UX and AIX).  There isn't a more portable solution to getting a reasonably good random seed that I'm aware of.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: C also works on Windows, DOS and embedded systems not based on Linux.  The question is not tagged Linux.

Comment: Well, you have to remember that C can run on Windows, too...