# Beginner having an issue with classes and functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am a beginner programmer working on a program in c++ visual studio 2015 that takes an instance of a class titled rect and passes it to a function within rect that sets a rectangle of random size and position somewhere on a imaginary board in a console window. At the bottom of the code there are full instructions on what the code needs to do. The problem I am having is when the program prints the rectangles, the rectangle of "0's" is not printing but the rectangle of "1's" is. The rectangle rect0 is being passed by reference and the rect1 is being passed by pointer.

```
/*
iLab2: rectangles
*/

#define NOMINMAX // prevent Windows API from conflicting with "min" and "max"

#include <stdio.h>   // C-style output. printf(char*,...), putchar(int)
#include <windows.h> // SetConsoleCursorPosition(HANDLE,COORD)
#include <conio.h>   // _getch()
#include <time.h>

/**
* moves the console cursor to the given x/y coordinate
* 0, 0 is the upper-left hand coordinate. Standard consoles are 80x24.
* @param x
* @param y
*/
void moveCursor(int x, int y)
{
    COORD c = { x,y };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), c);
}

struct Vec2
{
    short x, y;     // variables x and y for storing rectangle coordinates
    Vec2() : x(0), y(0) { }     // default constructor for vect2 if no parameters are specified
    Vec2(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) { } // default constructor for vect2 if parameters are given
    void operator+=(Vec2 v)     // function for adding or subtracting (if v is negative) to move the rectangle
    {
        x += v.x;
        y += v.y;
    }
};

class Rect
{
    Vec2 min, max;
public:
    Rect(int minx, int miny, int maxx, int maxy)
        :min(minx, miny), max(maxx, maxy)
    {}
    Rect() {}
    void draw(const char letter) const
    {
        for (int row = min.y; row < max.y; row++)
        {
            for (int col = min.x; col < max.x; col++)
            {
                if (row >= 0 && col >= 0)
                {
                    moveCursor(col, row);
                    putchar(letter);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void setMax(int maxx, int maxy)
    {
        this->max.x = maxx;
        this->max.y = maxy;
    }

    void setMin(int minx, int miny)
    {
        this->min.x = minx;
        this->min.y = miny;
    }
    bool isOverlapping(Rect const & r) const
    {
        return !(min.x >= r.max.x || max.x <= r.min.x
            || min.y >= r.max.y || max.y <= r.min.y);
    }
    void translate(Vec2 const & delta)
    {
        min+=(delta);
        max+=(delta);
    }
    void setRandom(Rect & r);
    void setRandom(Rect* r);
};


void Rect::setRandom(Rect & r)
{
    srand(time(NULL));      // added to make the random placement and size of the rect different each time program runs
    int pos_x, pos_y, height, width;
    pos_x = rand() % 51;
    pos_y = rand() % 21;

    height = 2 + rand() % 11;
    width = 2 + rand() % 11;

    height = height / 2;
    width = width / 2;

    r.min.x = pos_x - width;
    r.min.y = pos_y - height;
    r.max.x = pos_x + width;
    r.max.y = pos_y + height;
}
void Rect::setRandom(Rect * r)
{
    srand(time(NULL));      // added to make the random placement and size of the rect different each time program runs
    int posX, posY, heightPoint, widthPoint;
    posX = rand() % 51;
    posY = rand() % 21;

    heightPoint = 2 + rand() % 11;
    widthPoint = 2 + rand() % 11;

    heightPoint = heightPoint / 2;
    widthPoint = widthPoint / 2;

    this->min.x = posX - widthPoint;
    this->min.y = posY - heightPoint;
    this->max.x = posX + widthPoint;
    this->max.y = posY + heightPoint;
}

int main()
{
    // initialization
    //Rect userRect(7, 5, 10, 9);       // (x-min, y-min, x-max, y-max) x-min how far left the rectange can be
    //Rect rect0(10, 2, 14, 4);     // (x-min, y-min, x-max, y-max)
    //Rect rect1(1, 6, 5, 15);      // (x-min, y-min, x-max, y-max)
    //Rect userRect;
    Rect * userRect;
    Rect rect0;
    Rect rect1;
    const int rectSize = 5;
    Rect rect[rectSize];


    userRect = new Rect();
    // set
    rect[0].setRandom(rect[0]);
    rect[1].setRandom(& rect[1]);
    userRect->setMin(7, 5);
    userRect->setMax(10, 9);
    //rect0.setMin(10, 2);
    //rect0.setMax(14, 4);
    //rect1.setMin(1, 6);
    //rect1.setMax(5, 15);
    int userInput;

    do
    {
        // draw
        rect[0].draw('0');  // drawing the 0 rectangle with an x width of 4 and a y height of 2
        rect[1].draw('1');  // drawing the 1 rectangle with a x width of 4 and a y height of 9
        moveCursor(0, 0);   // re-print instructions
        printf("move with 'w', 'a', 's', and 'd'");
        userRect->draw('#');    // drawing the user rectangle in its starting location with a x width of 3 and a y height of 4
        // user input
        userInput = _getch();
        // update
        Vec2 move;
        switch (userInput)
        {
        case 'w':   move = Vec2(0, -1); break;      // Moves the user Rectangle -y or up on the screen
        case 'a':   move = Vec2(-1, 0); break;      // Moves the user Rectangle -x or left on the screen
        case 's':   move = Vec2(0, +1); break;      // Moves the user Rectangle +y or down on the screen
        case 'd':   move = Vec2(+1, 0); break;      // Moves the user Rectangle +x or right on the screen
        }
        userRect->draw(' ');    // un-draw before moving
        userRect->translate(move);      // moves the user rectangle to the new location
    } while (userInput != 27); // escape key
    delete userRect;    // delete dynamic object to release memory
    return 0;
}

// INSTRUCTIONS
// ------------
// 3) Random rectangles, by reference and by pointer
//   a) create a method with the method signature "void setRandom(Rect & r)".
//      This function will give the passed-in Rect object a random location.
//      The random x should be between 0 and 50 x. The random y should be  
//      between 0 and 20. Limit the possible width and height to a minimum of 2
//      and a maximum of 10.
//   b) test "void setRandom(Rect & r)" on the local Rect object "rect0".
//   c) create a method with the method signature
//      "void setRandomByPointer(Rect * r)", which functions the same as
//      "void setRandom(Rect & r)", except that the argument is
//      passed-by-pointer.
//   d) test "void setRandomByPointer(Rect * r)" on the local Rect object
//      "rect1".
// 4) Test and show overlap
//   a) Using the existing function "isOverlapping(Rect const &)", test to see
//      if userRect collides with any other Rect objects. If userRect is
//      overlapping, draw it with '+' instead '#'.
//   b) Create a Rect * pointer that points to the address if the Rect object
//      that userRect collides with. It should point at NULL if userRect is
//      colliding with no other Rect objects.
//   c) Print to the screen the width and height of a Rect object that userRect
//      collides with. If no collision is happening, print "no collision"
//      instead.
// 5) Array of objects
//   a) Replace the Rect objects rect0 and rect1 with an array of 2 Rect
//      objects, "rect[2]".
//   b) Make sure you replace every remaining "rect0" with "rect[0]", and every
//      "rect1" with "rect[1]".
//   c) Increase the size of the "rect" array to 5. Make sure all 5 Rect
//      objects are randomized, drawn to the screen, and tested for collision.
//   d) If you have not already done so, replace
//      duplicate-code-using-array-elements with a for-loop. For example:
//      If you have:
//          rect[0].draw('0');
//          rect[1].draw('1');
//          rect[2].draw('2');
//          rect[3].draw('3');
//          rect[4].draw('4');
//      Replace it with:
//          for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_RECTS; i++)
//          {
//              rect[i].draw('0'+i);
//          }
//      Do this where objects are randomized, drawn, and tested for collision
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different `setRandom()` methods with three problems.

1. Each time either `setRandom()` gets called, `srand()` also gets called. `srand()` [should only be called once, when the program starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322938/recommended-way-to-initialize-srand) -- read the first answer to that question, carefully.
2. Code duplication. The code in both `setRandom()` is nearly identical. Code duplication is bad. Duplicated code means that if the algorithm needs to be changed in some way, you will have to remember to do it in two places. Or three places. Or four places. Or however many duplicate chunks of code exist in the code. You have to remember them all, and find them. If you miss one, bugs galore.
3. Same problem as #2, but for the "nearly identical" part. The difference is: the first version of `setRandom()` takes a reference to another object and modifies another object that's passed by reference. The second version of `setRandom()` takes a pointer to another object instead of a reference, but ignores it completely, and instead initializes `this`, instead of the pointed object.

And, as a result of these bugs, we get the results you're seeing.

```
rect[0].setRandom(rect0);
```

This ends up initializing `rect0`. `rect[0]` is ignored completely, and not initialized at all.

```
rect[1].setRandom(& rect1);
```

This ends up initializing `rect[1]`. `rect1` is ignored completely, and not initialized at all.

And that's why the rest of the code fails to draw `rect[0]`. It does not get initialized at all.

The shown code is completely confused because it has four, and not two, objects. rect0, rect1, and the `rect[]` array containing two more objects. After they are declared, rect0 and rect1 are completely ignored, except for the misfired initialization, and they serve apparently no purpose whatsoever.

Neither is there any real reason here for `setRandom()` to take either a pointer or a reference to some other object. The apparent purpose of `setRandom()` is to initialize an object's dimensions randomly.

So it should simply initialize `this`'s dimensions randomly. Passing some other object, by pointer or reference, makes no sense at all.

Then, after getting rid of `rect0` and `rect1`, and simply calling a single `setRandom()` method...

```
rect[0].setRandom();
rect[1].setRandom();
```

... the rest of the code will proceed and properly draw two randomly-initialized objects.

Comment: Thanks so much the srand(time(NULL)); fix. This fixed my issue of rect[0] not printing. I actually just found issue with the passing rect0 instead of rect[0] and rect1  instead of [1].

Answer (score 0):

the code `Rect rect[ rectSize ]` will create 5 rects to array rect and all of those rects are with min(0,0) max(0,0)(initial state). when you call `rect[ 0 ].setRandom( rect0 )` which will update rect0(you pass it by reference) and do nothing to rect[0].when you call `rect[ 1 ].setRandom( &rect1 )` you update rect[1] (by this->min.x = posX - some value).so you get difference between rect[0] and rect[1].