# Can't get random numbers in c

Tags: c, random

I am trying to get two random numbers between 0 and 11 but i get the same number whenever i execute my code. These numbers are 7 and 10. Here is my code:

```
void track_machine(){
        int X = 0,Y = 0; //Coordinates
        double D = 0,R = 0; //Distance and replacement
        refresh_position(&X,&Y,&D,&R);
        printf("%d\n",X);
        printf("%d\n",Y);
}
void refresh_position(int *X, int *Y, double *D, double *R){
        *X = rand()%12;
        *Y = rand()%12;
}
```

Comment: Initialize the random generator `srand`, otherwise this will happen. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322938/recommended-way-to-initialize-srand)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recommended way to initialize srand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322938/recommended-way-to-initialize-srand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */
```

call `srand(time(NULL));` at the start of your program - before you use `rand()` - to set a different seed every time.

The "random-number-generator" is, despite its name, still a deterministic algorithm. When starting with the same seed values (when `srand` is not called), it will always produce the same results.

Comment: Sorry it asked me to wait 8 minute. Now I accepted.