# What is default seed?

Tags: c, random

When I call the following function:

```
printf("%d\n", rand())
srand(0);
printf("%d\n", rand());
```

I consistently get the following output:

```
1804289383
1804289383
```

What is this number representing before the `srand()`? And if the point is to make the `srand` required. Why isn't it initialized to something like `0` or `-1` or whatever?

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rand.3.html

Comment: @NickODell sure, but the sample implementation they give goes up to `32768-1` ?

Comment: https://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/random/

Comment: Tip: `rand()` is pretty trash as far as random number generators go, so don't rely on it for anything that needs truly secure or unpredictable random numbers.

Comment: `rand()` goes as high as `RAND_MAX`. The problem is that range varies considerably from one system to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "seed" sets the state of a pseudo-random number generator, albeit in a non-obvious way.  But whenever you seed it with the same number, you'll always get the next number back from `rand()`.  For the PRNG implementation in your C library (which appears to be glibc), it looks like a seed of 0 leads to a next random number of 1804289383.

There's nothing magic or meaningful about the number 1804289383, it just happens to be the number that your C library's PRNG kicks out after a seed value of 0.

Its a bit of a puzzle why the *previous* call to `rand()` -- the first one in your program -- is also returning that same value 1804289383.  That puzzled me quite a bit at first, because on startup th C library `rand()` is supposed to behave as if it had been seeded with a value of 1.  But as it turns out, the explanation is that glibc's PRNG also happens to turn a seed of 1 into a next value of 1804289383.

Thinking about `srand()` can be confusing.  For more explanation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once/40250047#40250047) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once), and also [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322938/recommended-way-to-initialize-srand).

Comment: With glibc's rand(), it's the same if it's seeded with 1 or 0.

Comment: @steve -- that was the first line in the `main` function so was doing nothing before.

Comment: @user414777 Thanks very much for pointing that out.  I had no idea.  Answer updated.