# What is the difference between int and long?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between an int and a long in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271076/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-a-long-in-c)
>   [difference in long vs int data types in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900230/difference-in-long-vs-int-data-types-in-c)

In c++ which is the diference between the int and long data type. Wrote the following code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout<<"Int_Max = "<<INT_MAX<<endl;
    cout<<"Int_Min = "<<INT_MIN<<endl;
    cout<<"Long_Max = "<<LONG_MAX<<endl;
    cout<<"Long_Min = "<<LONG_MIN<<endl;
}
```

And this were the results...

```
Int_Max = 2147483647
Int_Min = -2147483648
Long_Max = 2147483647
Long_Min = -2147483648
```

I'm confused.

Comment: Don't see where boost and game programming fit into that?

Comment: Or game programming, for that matter.

Comment: Answered before: [Link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900230/difference-in-long-vs-int-data-types-in-c)  [Link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271076/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-a-long-in-c)

Comment: I'm sorry for the boost thing, I was going to ask another question, and the tags remained. I edited already, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the standard, `int` is guaranteed to be at least 16 bits and `long` is at least 32 bits. On most 32-bit compilers they are just the same, both 32 bits. But you shouldn't count on this as there are 64-, 16- and even 8-bit compilers too.

Comment: The standard also guarantees the size of a char <= short <= int <= long. Interestingly, the standard does not mandate an 8-bit char, just that a char is at least 8-bits. It's possible for a char to be 9-bits in size, which would mean that you have a 9-bit byte.

Answer (score 3):

On 32-bit systems, there's usually no difference between `int` and `long`. If you want a 64-bit datatype on a 32-bit system, try `long long` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to guarantee the size of your data types, you should use the types in cstdint (requires C++0x support in g++, which is turned on by compiling with -std=c++0x). For instance, rather than int or long, you would use int32_t and int64_t. If you want an unsigned data type, simply add a 'u' to the beginning. uint16_t is probably equal to unsigned short on your platform. It's a 16-bit unsigned integer.

However, you should only use these where the exact space is important. Otherwise, "int" is generally preferable.

For a more complete reference, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h which includes other options such as int_least16_t for a data type that's at least 16 bits wide, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

char  : at least 8 bits  : equal to one unit

short : at least 16 bits : at least as wide as char

int   : at least 16 bits : at least as wide as short

long  : at least 32 bits : at least as wide as int