# Is int faster than long?

Tags: c++, types

Values `a` and `b` have same output:

```
int a = 0xEFEFEFEF;
long b = 0xEFEFEFEF;
cout << a << endl << b << endl;
```

I heard that a `long` type has more processing time to calculation because `long` should be cast to `int` for calculation. Is `int` really faster then `long`?

Comment: What `int` and `long` actually mean is compiler specific. Perhaps you could tell us which compiler you are using, and the system architecture you are targetting?

Comment: All C integral types depend on the platform (i.e. CPU and compiler). Your question cannot be answered in general without stating the platform.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900230/difference-in-long-vs-int-data-types-in-c

Answer (score 5):

This question is impossible to answer universally in a sense whether `long` is faster than `int`.

The code could be ran on a 16-bit platform with 32-bit `long` and 16-bit `int` on which the `int` would probably be faster - but not necessarily. On the other hand, on a native 32-bit platform which has 32-bit`int` and 64-bit `long`, the `long` could be faster - but not necessarily.

So it is platform dependent, and compiler dependent. The bottom line is that **usually** the operations on target CPU's *native* word length types are no slower(usually faster) than the operations which *may* require casting the width to native size.