# converting NSString to NSInteger in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsnumber

I have a string as

```
NSString *milliSeconds=@"1413808458821";
```

I tried the following to convert it to number, but None of them are giving correct value.

```
NSInteger number = [milliSeconds intValue];

NSInteger number = [milliSeconds integerValue];

NSInteger number = [milliSeconds longLongValue];
```

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably because you are running this code on a 32bit architecture, thus `NSInteger` is always an `int` and the number you're trying to convert is too big for this data type.

Try manually specifying the type to `long long`.

Comment: `long` == `int` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900230/difference-between-long-and-int-data-types

Comment: You are right, I made a typo. Thanks for pointing it out, I fixed the answer.