# Why in C++ do we use DWORD rather than unsigned int?

Tags: c++, winapi, types, dword

I'm not afraid to admit that I'm somewhat of a C++ newbie, so this might seem like a silly question but....

I see DWORD used all over the place in code examples. When I look up what a DWORD truly means, its apparently just an unsigned int (0 to 4,294,967,295). So my question then is, why do we have DWORD? What does it give us that the integral type 'unsigned int' does not? Does it have something to do with portability and machine differences?

Comment: It's not typical in c++ *per se*, it't typical in WinAPI.

Comment: BYTE = 1 letter/char<br>WORD = 2 letter/chars<br>DWORD = 4 letter/chars<br>QWORD = 8 letter/chars. D stand for "double". Q stand for "quad" quad are 2 double(s). D = 32-Bit, DD or Q = 64-Bit. in Assembly: "DB" for DataByte ( 1 times Char). "DW" for DoubleData(WORD - 2 times DB). "DD" for DoubleData(DWORD - 2 times DW). "DQ" for DoubleData(DDWORD - 2 times DD).

Answer (score 209, accepted):

`DWORD` is not a C++ type, it's defined in `<windows.h>`.

The reason is that `DWORD` has a specific range and format Windows functions rely on, so if you require that specific range use that type. (Or as they say "When in Rome, do as the Romans do.") For you, that happens to correspond to `unsigned int`, but that might not always be the case. To be safe, use `DWORD` when a `DWORD` is expected, regardless of what it may actually be.

For example, if they ever changed the range or format of `unsigned int` they could use a different type to underly `DWORD` to keep the same requirements, and all code using `DWORD` would be none-the-wiser. (Likewise, they could decide `DWORD` needs to be `unsigned long long`, change it, and all code using `DWORD` would be none-the-wiser.)

---

Also note `unsigned int` does *not* necessary have the range 0 to 4,294,967,295. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271076/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-a-long-in-c/271132#271132).

Comment: +1 the explanation. But I still would bet that if they did change DWORD a lot of programs would still break :)

Comment: A DWORD in windows 7 64 bit is unsigned long.  Thus it has changed for current developers.

Comment: @Milhous: According to the documentation, it is 32 bits: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230318.aspx.

Answer (score 113):

When MS-DOS and Windows 3.1 operated in 16-bit mode, an Intel 8086 word was 16 bits, a Microsoft WORD was 16 bits, a Microsoft DWORD was 32 bits, and a typical compiler's unsigned int was 16 bits.

When Windows NT operated in 32-bit mode, an Intel 80386 word was 32 bits, a Microsoft WORD was 16 bits, a Microsoft DWORD was 32 bits, and a typical compiler's unsigned int was 32 bits.  The names WORD and DWORD were no longer self-descriptive but they preserved the functionality of Microsoft programs.

When Windows operates in 64-bit mode, an Intel word is 64 bits, a Microsoft WORD is 16 bits, a Microsoft DWORD is 32 bits, and a typical compiler's unsigned int is 32 bits.  The names WORD and DWORD are no longer self-descriptive, AND an unsigned int no longer conforms to the principle of least surprises, but they preserve the functionality of lots of programs.

I don't think WORD or DWORD will ever change.

Comment: What is being referred to by "an unsigned int no longer conforms to the principle of least surprises"?

Comment: I presume he means that the size of int is no longer equal to the maximum native word size of the processor.

Comment: So, does this mean that this is has the same use as `stdint.h`/`cstdint` ?

Answer (score 14):

SDK developers prefer to define their own types using typedef. This allows changing underlying types only in one place, without changing all client code. It is important to follow this convention. DWORD is unlikely to be changed, but types like DWORD_PTR are different on different platforms, like Win32 and x64. So, if some function has DWORD parameter, use DWORD and not unsigned int, and your code will be compiled in all future windows headers versions.

Answer (score 13):

For myself, I would assume `unsigned int` is platform specific. Integers could be 16 bits, 32 bits or even 64 bits.

On the other hand, `DWORD` specifies its own size, which is Double Word. Words are 16 bits, so `DWORD` will be known as 32 bits across all platforms.

Comment: 8-bit `int` isn't allowed under the C or C++ standards.  But the point remains that there are platforms with 16-bit `int` and others with 32-bit `int`.

Comment: "Word are 16 bits" made sense in 1984 but really doesn't anymore :-(

Comment: "Word are 16 bits so DWORD will be known as 32 bit across all platform" - I'm pretty sure this is incorrect.  The term WORD relates more to hardware than software as it is really a term used to describe a single unit of data handled by a particular architecture's instruction set.  A WORD could be 8, 16, 32, 64, or any number of bits depending on the architecture.