# Why do we have multiple data types for primitives in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, primitive

In C/C++ each library has its own data types for primitive types. For example:

```
byte, word64, DWORD, LWORD, uint, unsigned int, size_t, ...
```

However in high-level languages such as Java and C#, everything is uniform (across all libraries).

In C/C++ programming, [beginner] people really get confused which data type should they use. For example, `byte` is defined as `unsigned char`, so why do we need `byte` at all?

I think this could be a source for many memory leaks and other problems (such as many vulnerabilities) at least for beginners. I still can't figure out what's the point of having such data types while a minimal set of them is enough?

The same problem is for `null` pointer as we have:

```
NULL, 0, _null, ...
```

And all are defined as `0`.

---

**Update #1:**

As @CoryKramer stated the reason could be because of cross-platform compatibility, and interoperability. So, another question which comes to my mind, is that why don't standards define a uniform, cross-platform and inter-operable data types?

Comment: A combination of historical reasons, cross-platform compatibility, and interoperability much of which are too broad for a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: @CoryKramer historical reasons?

Comment: One reason is that integer widths vary across platforms. Thankfully, we have standard `[u]intN_t` types now. Also, there's `nullptr` for a proper null pointer. I've never seen `_null`.

Comment: Yes, specifically things like `DWORD` and `LWORD`, [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995251/why-in-c-do-we-use-dword-rather-than-unsigned-int)

Comment: C does not define `byte`.  Possible some compiler you used does that various reasons, but the language does not do it.

Comment: Same reason as  we have 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 when 0,1 as  a minimal set is enough? For a truly minimal set see [Turing Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine)

Comment: @chris: `nullptr` isn't C, but C++.

Comment: One reason is just the fact that there's typedef in C and C++, but not in C#. You can make your own types, but basically they are just aliases. C++11 and nullptr solves the NULL issues.

Comment: Please understand that C and C++ are different languages. It mostly never is a good idea to tag question C *and* C++.

Comment: To answer your update, they *do* have fixed-size integral types for those reasons, they're in the [`<cstdint>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint) header

Comment: If doing C, check if POSIX support/compatibility is an option and switch to using the types from `stdint.h`: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdint.h.html

Comment: @chris  `_null` is the pre C++11 GCC version of `nullptr`.

Comment: @CoryKramer So, why don't _all_ libraries comply those standards for data types and instead define their own data types using `typedef`?

Comment: Because C is a "free" language, not "owned" by anybody? ;-) (since long)

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto - Some of these code bases are from long before C++ was standardized. Windows with DWORD, LPARAM etc started out in 1985!  Also, Java and C# can *get away* with a single size for each type, because they both only run on a single platform, the JVM or .NET. C and C++ are designed to be able to run on a *very* wide variety of systems.

Comment: @sbabbi, Interesting, thanks. I'm surprised I didn't know that then.

Comment: @BoPersson: "*Java ... because .. [it] ... only run[s] on a single platform...*" Really?

Comment: @alk - Yes, really. Before you can run Java on your platform, you have to port a JVM. And that one is standardized.

Comment: @BoPersson: ok but on the other hand, there is also Rust, which runs on most systems and also has only standard integer types. So having something like the JVM or .NET is not really the reason that a language can get away with this, that's only incidental. You don't need to have a special runtime to have guaranteed fixed size integer types -- you just might not be as portable if you do

Comment: @BoPersson: Sure, you are correct. I somehow fell back to some piece other discussion ... ;-)