# AccessViolationException when try to read memory from pointer in C# using Marshal class

Tags: c#, winapi, marshalling, unmanaged

I try to create a program that will programatically set Windows Color Management to archive an effect like f.lux as a hobby project.

**The definition of WINAPI `WcsGetDefaultColorProfileSize`. **

```
BOOL WINAPI WcsGetDefaultColorProfileSize(
  _In_      WCS_PROFILE_MANAGEMENT_SCOPE profileManagementScope,
  _In_opt_  PCWSTR pDeviceName,
  _In_      COLORPROFILETYPE cptColorProfileType,
  _In_      COLORPROFILESUBTYPE cpstColorProfileSubType,
  _In_      DWORD dwProfileID,
  _Out_     PDWORD pcbProfileName
);
```

**This is the signature of managed `WcsGetDefaultColorProfileSize`. **

```
[DllImport("Mscms.dll", EntryPoint = "WcsGetDefaultColorProfileSize", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern bool GetDefaultColorProfileSize(
  WCS_PROFILE_MANAGEMENT_SCOPE profileManagementScope,
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr), In] string pDeviceName,
  COLORPROFILETYPE cptColorProfileType,
  COLORPROFILESUBTYPE cpstColorProfileSubType,
  Int32 dwProfileID,
  out IntPtr pcbProfileSize
);
```

**The problem is when I try to get the string which is return as a pointer from WINAPI using Marshal class. Like this**

```
// Need to get the size of ICC profile file first
GetDefaultColorProfileSize(
WCS_PROFILE_MANAGEMENT_SCOPE.WCS_PROFILE_MANAGEMENT_SCOPE_CURRENT_USER, 
monitor_name.DeviceKey, 
COLORPROFILETYPE.CPT_ICC, 
COLORPROFILESUBTYPE.CPST_RGB_WORKING_SPACE, 
1,
out SizePointer);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Size is " + Marshal.ReadInt32(SizePointer));
```

the `GetDefaultColorProfileSize` return `TRUE` but when I try to access the address it return (It return this address 0x0000003e) using `Marshal.ReadInt32`
It throw this error

> System.AccessViolationException Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

How can I able to read the memory at that pointer?

I try to allocate the memory first as suggesting by **nvoigt**

Changing from `IntPtr SizePointer` to `IntPtr SizePointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(4);`

But it  still throw the same exception

### The full code is below here.

#### Enumnerate Display Devices

```
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern bool EnumDisplayDevices(
        string lpDevice, int iDevNum,
        ref DISPLAY_DEVICE lpDisplayDevice, int dwFlags);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DISPLAY_DEVICE
    {
        public int cb;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
        public string DeviceName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
        public string DeviceString;
        public int StateFlags;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
        public string DeviceID;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
        public string DeviceKey;

        public DISPLAY_DEVICE(int flags) {
            cb = 0;
            StateFlags = flags;
            DeviceName = new string((char)32, 32);
            DeviceString = new string((char)32, 128);
            DeviceID = new string((char)32, 128);
            DeviceKey = new string((char)32, 128);
            cb = Marshal.SizeOf(this);
        }
    }
```

#### Window Color System

```
    enum WCS_PROFILE_MANAGEMENT_SCOPE
    {
        WCS_PROFILE_MANAGEMENT_SCOPE_SYSTEM_WIDE = 0,
        WCS_PROFILE_MANAGEMENT_SCOPE_CURRENT_USER
    }

    enum COLORPROFILETYPE
    {
        CPT_ICC = 0x0001,
        CPT_DMP,
        CPT_CAMP,
        CPT_GMMP
    }

    enum COLORPROFILESUBTYPE
    {
        CPST_NONE = 0x0000,
        CPST_RGB_WORKING_SPACE = 0x0001,
        CPST_PERCEPTUAL = 0x0002,
        CPST_ABSOLUTE_COLORIMETRIC = 0x0004,
        CPST_RELATIVE_COLORIMETRIC = 0x0008,
        CPST_SATURATION = 0x0010,
        CPST_CUSTOM_WORKING_SPACE = 0x0020
    }
    [DllImport("Mscms.dll", EntryPoint = "WcsGetDefaultColorProfileSize", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern bool GetDefaultColorProfileSize(
      WCS_PROFILE_MANAGEMENT_SCOPE profileManagementScope,
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr), In] string pDeviceName,
      COLORPROFILETYPE cptColorProfileType,
      COLORPROFILESUBTYPE cpstColorProfileSubType,
      Int32 dwProfileID,
      out IntPtr pcbProfileSize
    );
    [DllImport("Mscms.dll", EntryPoint = "WcsGetDefaultColorProfile" , CharSet =CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError =true)]
    private unsafe static extern bool GetDefaultColorProfile(WCS_PROFILE_MANAGEMENT_SCOPE profileManagementScope,
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr), In] string pDeviceName,
          COLORPROFILETYPE cptColorProfileType,
          COLORPROFILESUBTYPE cpstColorProfileSubType,
          Int32 dwProfileID,
          Int32 cbProfileName,
          out IntPtr pProfileName);

    [DllImport("Mscms.dll", EntryPoint = "WcsSetUsePerUserProfiles", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern bool SetUsePerUserProfiles([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr), In]string pDeviceName, Int32 dwDeviceClass, bool usePerUserProfiles);
    [DllImport("Mscms.dll", EntryPoint = "WcsGetUsePerUserProfiles", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern bool GetUsePerUserProfiles([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr), In]string pDeviceName, Int32 dwDeviceClass, out bool pUsePerUserProfiles);
```

### The Actual Code

```
    public unsafe static void GetProfile() {
        DISPLAY_DEVICE lpDisplayDevice = new DISPLAY_DEVICE(0);     // OUT
        DISPLAY_DEVICE monitor_name = new DISPLAY_DEVICE(0);        // OUT

        int devNum = 0;
        while (EnumDisplayDevices(null, devNum, ref lpDisplayDevice, 0)) {
            int devNum2 = 0;
            while (EnumDisplayDevices(lpDisplayDevice.DeviceName, devNum2, ref monitor_name, 0)) {
              IntPtr SizePointer;
              // Need to get the size of ICC profile file first
                GetDefaultColorProfileSize(
  WCS_PROFILE_MANAGEMENT_SCOPE.WCS_PROFILE_MANAGEMENT_SCOPE_CURRENT_USER, 
                    monitor_name.DeviceKey, 
                    COLORPROFILETYPE.CPT_ICC, 
                    COLORPROFILESUBTYPE.CPST_RGB_WORKING_SPACE, 
                    1,
                    out SizePointer);
              System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Size is " + Marshal.ReadInt32(SizePointer));
            // Try to get a location of ICC profile file.
             // Not Implement Yet
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: We need more bold text.

Comment: Sorry then, I have now fix the question to be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Your `SizePointer` is a local variable that you never used. I don't know what you *expect* to happen, but this is not going to work. You probably meant to use `profileSize`.

In the future, you should fix your warnings first. They are important.

---

Okay, now you are at least passing the correct variable. You still have not initialized it to anything. You are passing a NULL pointer to a method that is supposed to write there. It won't be able to. I cannot imagine you actually got a `TRUE` back from that method. And reading from a NULL pointer will obviously fail. You need to make sure that pointer actually points to a part in memory that can be written to.

You need a [DWORD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995251/why-in-c-do-we-use-dword-rather-than-unsigned-int). As you are using `ReadInt32`, I'll assume you are on 32bit.

You need to allocate memory first:

```
int size = 4; // 4 byte = 32 bit

IntPtr p = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
```

Don't forget to free it later, this is not garbage collected:

```
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(p);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it is a typo when I copied the code to StackOverflow and cut some unimportant lines of code. The actual code I've run in VS2015 is corrected. I've fix the typo as you mentioned already.

Comment: Nobody wants to help if you post fake code and then tell us that we are answering the wrong question, as if that is our fault. Frankly we don't care what your code actually is. We only care about the question in front of us. If you post code that bears no relation to the code in front of you, then that's on you. Please do not ever post fake code.

Comment: @nvoigt I have tried but it still throw the exception. The pointer that `WcsGetDefaultColorProfileSize` which returns 'TRUE' returns  `out IntPtr SizePointer` is always "0x0000003e". When I open Memory Window in VS and search this address. It only shows ?? ?? ?? ??.

Comment: @Suttisak I will not comment on code I cannot see. If you tried, **post the code**.