# Is int guaranteed to be 32 bits on each platform supported by Qt, or only qint32?

Tags: c++, qt, types, size, int

I remember reading somewhere that Qt guarantees the size of some data types on supported platforms. Is it that `int` will be *at least* 32 bits everywhere, and `qint32` will be *exactly* 32 bits everywhere? Or something else?

C++ guarantees that `int` will be at least 16 bits, and some Qt structures like `QRect` and `QPoint` use `int` internally. I'm developing an application where 32 bits is needed with those types, and I don't want to have to duplicate their functionality so I can use a larger type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The size of an integer type is up to the compiler. I don't think there's a guarantee that plain `int` will be of a precise size. But you can make sure you know it's not what you want by adding this line to the beginning of your `main()`:

```
if(sizeof(int) != 4) {
  throw std::runtime_error("int is not 32-bit");
}
```

Comment: Ok, but, `QtGlobal` defines several typedefs. For example, the documentation for qint32 says "Typedef for signed int. This type is guaranteed to be 32-bit on all platforms supported by Qt.". So this means that `int` must also be guaranteed to be 32 bits on all platforms supported?

Comment: I would not derive that conclusion. The doc guarantees that qint32 will be of 32-bit size on all supported platforms, not the other way around.

If they have to support a platform in the future that int is not 32-bit, they will change the typedef for that platform to reflect that.

As it's implemented now, you can assume all platforms supported by Qt have 32-bit int. But assumption is a VERY EVIL thing.

Comment: The purpose of qint32 and friends is to provide a type with a guaranteed signedness and size. If the standard types would provide that, one wouldn't need those Qt typedefs ;)
I guess the Qt documentation is ambiguously worded here.

Comment: You can't know how many bits there are in `int` by checking its size with `sizeof`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/271076/95735

Comment: @Piotr: are you going to test that on *each platform supported by Qt*? Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

While, as far as I know, it's technically possible that int isn't 32bits, I've never seen a platform where it isn't. Imagine- char, 8bits, short, 16bits, int, .. 24bits? It simply doesn't fit the hierarchy for int to be non-32bits.

In addition, you can use UINT_MAX to confirm int's size on your given compiler.

Comment: There are tons of microcontrollers where int is 16 bit.

Comment: Size (obtained by using `sizeof` operator) and **minimal** number of bits (so that the value of `UINT_MAX` could be represented) are two different things. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/271076/95735