# Size of #define values

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

If a value is defined as

`#define M_40        40`

Is the size the same as a `short` (2 bytes) or is it as a `char` (1 byte) or `int` (4 bytes)?

Is the size dependent on whether you are 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: Who says a `short` is going to be 2 bytes or an `int` is going to be 4 bytes? These are the only guarantees you have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271076/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-a-long-in-c/271132#271132

Comment: @GMan: Good link.. In my compiler and environment, it is 2 bytes so I should have clarified.. thanks

Comment: This question is tagged with C++, so I assume that's what your programming in. There's no good reason to use `#define` for this sort of thing in C++. Just write `const int M_40 = 40;` and be done with it. You can then change the `int` to `short` or `char` or whatever you like if you care about size. Also, it's kind of missing the point of named constants if the constant's name is just it's value. Writing `foo(M_40)` isn't exactly any clearer in meaning than `foo(40)`.

Comment: @Tyler: Well, I simplified the context so M_40 means message 40 in my particular application. I agree on the constness though

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`#define` has no size as it's not a type but a plain text substitution into your C++ code.  `#define` is a preprocessing directive and it runs before your code even begins to be compiled .

The size in C++ code after substitution is whatever the size is of what C++ expression or code you have there. For example if you suffix with `L` like `102L` then it is seen a long, otherwise with no suffix, just an int.    So 4 bytes on x86 and x64 probably, but this is compiler dependent.

Perhaps the C++ standard's Integer literal section will clear it up for you (Section 2.13.1-2 of the C++03 standard):

> The type of an integer literal depends
>   on its form, value, and suffix. If it
>   is decimal and has no suffix, it has
>   the first of these types in which its
>   value can be represented: int, long
>   int; if the value cannot be
>   represented as a long int, the
>   behavior is undefined. If it is octal
>   or hexadecimal and has no suffix, it
>   has the first of these types in which
>   its value can be represented: int,
>   unsigned int, long int, unsigned long
>   int. If it is suffixed by u or U, its
>   type is the first of these types in
>   which its value can be represented:
>   unsigned int, unsigned long int. If it
>   is suffixed by l or L, its type is the
>   first of these types in which its
>   value can be represented: long int,
>   unsigned long int. If it is suffixed
>   by ul, lu, uL, Lu, Ul, lU, UL, or LU,
>   its type is unsigned long int

Answer (score 8):

A plain integer is going to be implicitly cast to `int` in all calculations and assignments.

`#define` simply tells the preprocessor to replace all references to a symbol with something else. This is the same as doing a global find-replace on your code and replacing `M_40` with `40`.

Comment: +1 Global find-replace is the clearest, most newbie-friendly explanation

Answer (score 2):

A #define value has no size, specifically.  It's just text substitution.  It depends on the context of where (and what) is being substituted.

In your example, where you use `M_40`, the compile will see `40`, and usually treat it as in `int`.

However, if we had:

```
void SomeFunc(long);

SomeFunc(M_40);
```

It will be treated as a long.

Comment: Not usually, always. And the constant `40` will still be an `int` in your example code. However, the value `40` will be promoted to a `long` upon calling the function. But `40` the constant is still an `int`.

Comment: @GMan: Why is it still an int even though it could be a simple 1-byte char? Edit (Yes I know char isn't necessarily 1-byte)

Comment: @GMan:  #define L(X) X##L    L(M_40)   now it's a long.
     #define S(X) #X     S(M_40)  now it's a char*, which is why I said "usually".

Comment: @Changeling: It's just how the language is defined, it's in §2.13/1 in the standard. Without a suffix, the type of the literal will be an `int`; if it cannot fit, it will be a `long int`. If it cannot fit into either of those, the behavior is undefined. Also, a `char` is always 1 byte. :) (A byte might not necessarily be 8 bytes, though. Generally, people use "octect" to refer to a collection of 8 bytes.)

Comment: @GMam: also, the promotion here happens at compile time, making the difference between "an int promoted to a long" and "be[ing] treated as a long" a very grey area.

Comment: @James: `40` is a literal that has the type `int`, always and forever. When calling the function, the parameter will be initialized as `long(40)`. In that context, `40` is still a literal with the type `int`. (And the entire expression yields a `long`, promoted from an `int` value.) And in response to your alternative macro, that's like: "Is this an apple?"  "Yes" "*squishes it* No it's not, it's apple juice!". Yes `40L` is no longer an `int`...nor is it `40` anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Preprocessor macros get literally swapped in during the preprocess stage of the compilation.

For example the code

```
#define N 5

int value = N;
```

will get swapped for

```
int value = 5;
```

when the compiler sees it. It does not have a size of its own as such

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor just does simple text substitution, so the fact that your constant is in a `#define` doesn't matter.  All the C standard says is that "Each constant shall have a type and the value of a constant shall be in the range of representable values for its type."  C++ is likely to not vary too much from that.

Comment: Going further, what makes C++ cast the value into an `int` instead of char when 40 is an acceptable value for example, unsigned char since it is between 0 and 255?

Comment: @Changeling: Based on the C++ standard rules.