# Write Raster using GDAL C API

Tags: c, gdal

I am trying to get my head around the GDAL C API.
I have some arrays which contains int, float or double values and when I try to dump them to a tiff file using GDALRasterIO I get raster with vertical band alternating with 0 values (uninitialised values I suspect...

Here is a minimal example:

```
#include "gdal.h"

void create_new_tiff(char * DstFilename, int nx, int ny);

int main()
{
char  filename[10] = "test.tif";
int nx, ny;

nx = 600;
ny = 500;

create_new_tiff(filename, nx, ny);

return 0;
}
```

And the create_new_tiff function:

```
void create_new_tiff(char * DstFilename, int nx, int ny)
{

const char *pszFormat = "GTiff";
int test[nx*ny];
GDALDatasetH hDstDS;
GDALRasterBandH hBand;
char **papszOptions = NULL;

GDALAllRegister();
GDALDriverH hDriver = GDALGetDriverByName( pszFormat );

hDstDS = GDALCreate( hDriver, DstFilename, nx, ny, 1, GDT_Int16, papszOptions);
hBand = GDALGetRasterBand( hDstDS, 1 );

for(int i=0; i<nx*ny; i++) test[i] = 4;

CPLErr Err = GDALRasterIO( hBand, GF_Write, 0, 0, nx, ny, test, nx, ny, GDT_Int16, 0, 0);
GDALClose( hDstDS );
}
```

Looks like I am confusing data type but can't figure out what is wrong...

Thanks

PS: Here is what the raster looks like in QGis:

[image]

Comment: int is GDT_Int32.  Change your array to short, or your data type to GDT_Int32.

Comment: Isn't “int" 16 bits ?

Comment: OK I thought int was 2 bytes by default but it actually depends on the implementation.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946268/is-int-by-default-long-int-in-c

Comment: Actually it does not work. I have a raster with NaN values only...

Comment: That maybe QGIS just misinterpreting the values.  Fiddle with the style, and load the 'actual' min/max from the raster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake comes from the fact that I was assuming that "int" was actually 2 bytes by default which is wrong. The size of int depends on the implementation. See [is int by default long int in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946268/is-int-by-default-long-int-in-c)

See kyle comment