# size guarantee for integral/arithmetic types in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, sizeof, primitive-types

I know that the C++ standard explicitly guarantees the size of only `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char`. Also it gives guarantees that, say, `short` is at least as big as `char`, `int` as big as `short` etc. But no explicit guarantees about absolute value of, say, `sizeof(int)`. This was the info in my head and I lived happily with it. Some time ago, however, I came across a comment in SO (can't find it) that in C `long` is guaranteed to be at least 4 bytes, and that requirement is "inherited" by C++. Is that the case? If so, what other implicit guarantees do we have for the sizes of arithmetic types in C++? Please note that I am absolutely not interested in *practical* guarantees across different platforms in this question, just *theoretical* ones.

Comment: "Somewhere on the Internet, someone said something, which I read, but now I can't find, and I'm not sure what it was exactly either, and I have forgotten what facts it was based on (_if_ it was based on any) and what its reasoning was. But, please, could you dispute with its reasonings and either confirm or deny it?" There's a Radio Yerevan joke hidden in there, but now that I've stabbed at it for 5mins, it's scared and won't come out of its hiding. `:)`

Comment: @sbi: Oh, come on, you're exaggerating :). Incidentally I *am* from Yerevan :)

Comment: In C, there's *absolutely* no guarantee of `long` being at least 4 bytes wide. This, of course is also true for C++. However, `long` is *always* `sizeof long` bytes.

Comment: @eq-: There is no guarantee that a `long` has to be at least 4 bytes wide, but it does implicitly say it has to be at least 32 bits wide based on a minimum range it gives. This almost always means 4 bytes since a byte is 8 bits on most (but not all!) architectures.

Comment: @In silico: Yes, I was being pedantic. However, long by no means means[sic] 4 bytes these days - it's very common (one could say de facto) to have 64-bit long in 64-bit *NIX OS's.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

18.2.2 guarantees that `<climits>` has the same contents as the C library header `<limits.h>`.

The ISO C90 standard is tricky to get hold of, which is a shame considering that C++ relies on it, but the section "Numerical limits" (numbered 2.2.4.2 in a random draft I tracked down on one occasion and have lying around) gives minimum values for the `INT_MAX` etc. constants in `<limits.h>`. For example  `ULONG_MAX` must be at least 4294967295, from which we deduce that the width of `long` is at least 32 bits.

There are similar restrictions in the C99 standard, but of course those aren't the ones referenced by C++03.

This does *not* guarantee that `long` is at least 4 bytes, since in C and C++ "byte" is basically defined to mean "char", and it is not guaranteed that `CHAR_BIT` is 8 in C or C++. `CHAR_BIT == 8` is guaranteed by both POSIX and Windows.

Comment: Thanks! I will accept this answer because it covers all aspects. I am also thankful for all other answers, because all of them carry valuable information.

Comment: According to the post by pmg, `CHAR_BIT >= 8` is guaranteed. Is that your understanding too?

Comment: @Mark: yes, that restriction is in my C89 draft too (same section). It's certainly in C99 (5.2.4.2.1/1), for what that's worth. I should really get a trustworthy copy of C89 or C90, but last time I seriously needed one, we had one in the office.

Answer (score 12):

Don't know about C++. In C you have

```
                                  Annex E
                              (informative)


                          Implementation limits

       [#1]  The contents of the header  are given below,
       in alphabetical order.  The minimum magnitudes  shown  shall
       be  replaced  by  implementation-defined magnitudes with the
       same sign.  The values shall  all  be  constant  expressions
       suitable  for  use  in  #if  preprocessing  directives.  The
       components are described further in 5.2.4.2.1.

               #define CHAR_BIT                         8
               #define CHAR_MAX    UCHAR_MAX or SCHAR_MAX
               #define CHAR_MIN            0 or SCHAR_MIN
               #define INT_MAX                     +32767
               #define INT_MIN                     -32767
               #define LONG_MAX               +2147483647
               #define LONG_MIN               -2147483647
               #define LLONG_MAX     +9223372036854775807
               #define LLONG_MIN     -9223372036854775807
               #define MB_LEN_MAX                       1
               #define SCHAR_MAX                     +127
               #define SCHAR_MIN                     -127
               #define SHRT_MAX                    +32767
               #define SHRT_MIN                    -32767
               #define UCHAR_MAX                      255
               #define USHRT_MAX                    65535
               #define UINT_MAX                     65535
               #define ULONG_MAX               4294967295
               #define ULLONG_MAX    18446744073709551615
```

So `char` <= `short` <= `int` <= `long` <= `long long`

and

CHAR_BIT * sizeof (char) >= 8
CHAR_BIT * sizeof (short) >= 16
CHAR_BIT * size of (int) >= 16
CHAR_BIT * sizeof (long) >= 32
CHAR_BIT * sizeof (long long) >= 64

Comment: sizeof(char) == 1 per definition.  sizeof measures in units of char

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271076/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-a-long-in-c/271132#271132

Answer (score 3):

Yes, C++ type sizes are inherited from C89.

I can't find the specification right now. But it's in the [Bible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language_%28book%29).

Comment: Which clause in the C++ standard implies that guarantees from C89 are also valid for C++?

Comment: I don't remember section and paragraph, sorry. But it just delegates to the C89 standard.

Comment: @Armen: 18.2.2/2: "The contents are the same as the C standard library header `<limits.h>`."

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that the guaranteed ranges of these types are one less wide than on most machines:

signed char   -127 ... +127 guranteed but most twos complement machines have -128 ... + 127

Likewise for the larger types.

Comment: Likely to account for the possibility of ones complement.

Answer (score 3):

There are several inaccuracies in what you read. These inaccuracies were either present in the source, or maybe you remembered it all incorrectly.

Firstly, a pedantic remark about one peculiar difference between C and C++. C language does not make any guarantees about the relative *sizes* of integer types (in bytes). C language only makes guarantees about their relative *ranges*. It is true that the range of `int` is always at least as large as the range of `short` and so on. However, it is formally allowed by C standard to have `sizeof(short) > sizeof(int)`. In such case the extra bits in `short` would serve as *padding bits*, not used for value representation. Obviously, this is something that is merely allowed by the legal language in the standard, not something anyone is likely to encounter in practice.

In C++ on the other hand, the language specification makes guarantees about both the relative *ranges* and relative *sizes* of the types, so in C++ in addition to the above range relationship inherited from C it is guaranteed that `sizeof(int)` is greater or equal than `sizeof(short)`.

Secondly, the C language standard guarantees minimum range for each integer type (these guarantees are present in both C and C++). Knowing the minimum range for the given type, you can always say how many value-forming *bits* this type is required to have (as minimum number of bits). For example, it is true that type `long` is required to have at least 32 value-forming bits in order to satisfy its range requirements. If you want to recalculate that into *bytes*, it will depend on what you understand under the term *byte*. If you are talking specifically about 8-bit bytes, then indeed type `long` will always consist of at least four 8-bit bytes. However, that does not mean that `sizeof(long)` is always at least 4, since in C/C++ terminology the term *byte* refers to `char` objects. `char` objects are not limited to 8-bits. It is quite possible to have 32-bit `char` type in some implementation, meaning that `sizeof(long)` in C/C++ bytes can legally be 1, for example.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard do not explicitly say that `long` has to be at least 4 bytes, but they do specify a minimum range for the different integral types, which implies a minimum size.

For example, the minimum range of an `unsigned long` is 0 to 4,294,967,295. You need at least 32 bits to represent every single number in that range. So yes, the standard guarantee (indirectly) that a `long` is at least 32 bits.

C++ inherits the data types from C, so you have to go look at the C standard. The C++ standard actually references to parts of the C standard in this case.

Comment: Can this be found in the C++ standard?

Comment: The Standard guarantees that a long has at least 32 bits (not 4 bytes: a byte can be 32 bits long)

Comment: My copy of the C++ standard does not include this. (2003)

Answer (score 1):

Just be careful about the fact that some machines have chars that are more than 8 bits. For example, IIRC on the TI C5x, a long is 32 bits, but sizeof(long)==2 because chars, shorts and ints are all 16 bits with sizeof(char)==1.