# Difference between 4-byte types in 32-bit and 64-bit Linux machines

Tags: c++, linux, 64-bit, size, porting

I am porting our Linux C++ project from 32-bit to 64-bit.

In our 32-bit system, "long" is 4-bytes long. But when we built our project in 64-bit mode, we noticed that "long" is taking 8-bytes. Since we need 4-byte long type, we used "int" and confirmed that it is indeed 4-bytes long. And we were hoping that our code works seamlessly.

But unfortunately no, even though "long" in 32-bit mode and "int" in 64-bit mode are 4-bytes long both, our code is failing.

Could someone please let us know if there is a difference (in layout or something else) between "long" in 32-bit mode and "int" in 64-bit mode? Even though both are 4-bytes long?

- Machine: Linux x86_64
- OS: CentOS 6.6
- gcc: 4.9.2

Comment: I am not sure about your question, but is there a reason you can't used [fixed width types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)?

Comment: What kind of failures are you experiencing?

Comment: We tried that as well. We need a 4-byte long type in 64-bit mode and we tried uint32_t. Our code needs 4-byte types regardless of underlying mode (32-bit v/s 64-bit). But unfortunately that same block of code is failing badly. There is nothing else in that code, just some bit-wise operators and that piece of code works perfectly in 32-bit mode.

Comment: bit-wise shift operations are failing and returning incorrect results in 64-bit mode (with 4-byte long "uint32_t" and "int").

Comment: To answer the question in your post. No. You have a bug somewhere in your code.

Comment: Maybe post a snippet of the code that is actually failing and people can help you with that.  That may solve your problem entirely or help with the possibly larger problem of getting the types portably correct in general.

Comment: have you tried int32_t?

Comment: It's impossible to tell why your code fails with the information you've given us. I believe the layout for 32-bit integers should be the same for 32-bit and 64-bit mode. One suggestion: `int` is 32 bits in both 32-bit and 64-bit mode (that's not universal, but it's likely true for your system). Does your modified code work in 32-bit mode? Finally, if you really need a particular width, you really should be using fixed-width types.

Comment: *bit-wise shift operations are failing and returning incorrect results in 64-bit mode (with 4-byte long "uint32_t" and "int")* -- Update your question with a small program that illustrates this.

Comment: Could you show us where it crashes? The problem might be something else than types size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone. The issue was something local/specific to our code, where we were making an assumption that pointers are always 4-bytes long. When we were dereferencing them, we were casting them to 4-byte variables and were losing precision. This was causing crashes. Since this is a large codebase developed by many people over many years, there was lot of legacy code with these assumptions, I had to go over all the pointers and modify them. And finally we have ported our code successfully to 64-bit mode.

Comment: I'm interested. Where , and how often would pointers not adequately be stored in a normal `int` ? Since I'm doing this here and there in a couple of my own projects (though mostly only the difference of two pointers)

Answer (score 1):

If you need byte-length specific data types, look into `int32_t` and `uint32_t` from [`cstdint`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)
.

The types are guaranteed to be the given length, signed and unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this -  [Size guarantees in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091826/size-guarantee-for-integral-arithmetic-types-in-c-and-c). The built-in types (int , long etc.) satisfy some minimum sizes but they need not be 4 bytes on every system. You can use fixed width types (as mentioned in a comment by dwcanillas).