# Convert array of bytes to uint64_t?

Tags: c, arrays, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, endianness

I have a large array of bytes called memory and I'm trying to convert 8 of those bytes to a uint64_t. I'm trying to print the number in big-endian.

I have this so far:

```
uint64_t value =  (uint64_t)(memory[256]) | //location contains byte 88
   (uint64_t)(memory[257]) << 8  |          //77
   (uint64_t)(memory[258]) << 16 |          //66
   (uint64_t)(memory[259]) << 24 |          //55
   (uint64_t)(memory[260]) << 32 |          //44
   (uint64_t)(memory[261]) << 40 |          //33
   (uint64_t)(memory[262]) << 48 |          //22
   (uint64_t)(memory[263]) << 56;           //11
```

I print like so:

```
printf("0x%x", value);
```

The output is `0x55667788`, but I want the output to be `0x1122334455667788`.

Any suggestions of how I can fix the above code to print `0x1122334455667788`?

Solution: The print statement needed to be:

```
printf("0x%lx", value);
```

Comment: Is the compiler warning you about something?

Comment: I dont know abt this.. But i found a similar problem here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142251/convert-array-of-8-bytes-to-signed-long-in-c

Comment: I'm not getting one, no.

Comment: Are you asking the compiler to give you warnings?

Comment: let me try that

Comment: %08x didn't work :( but I am getting a warning - "format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘uint64_t {aka long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("%08x", value);"

Comment: Yeah, that is my mistake. Try using %lx (or %llx)

Comment: %lx worked! glad to know it was just the print statement. Thanks!

Comment: _I'm trying to print the number in big-endian._ [Bit-shift are endian independent](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7184789/1606345)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format specifier `%lx` works because the `unsigned long` type happens to have at least 64 bits on your system.  The C Standard does not guarantee that and indeed it has only 32 bits on 64-bit Microsoft Windows. `unsigned long long` is guaranteed to have at least 64 bits, so you could use this:

```
printf("0x%llx\n", (unsigned long long)value);
```

If your compiler and C library support C99 or a later standard, you can use the macros defined in `<inttypes.h>`:

```
printf("0x%" PRIx64 "\n", value);
```