# What is wrong with this bit-manipulation code from an interview question?

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, integer-promotion

I was having a look over this page: http://www.devbistro.com/tech-interview-questions/Cplusplus.jsp, and didn't understand this question:

> #### What’s potentially wrong with the following code?
>
> ```
> long value;
> //some stuff
> value &= 0xFFFF;
> ```
>
> Note: Hint to the candidate about the base platform they’re developing for. If the person still doesn’t find anything wrong with the code, they are not experienced with C++.

Can someone elaborate on it?

Thanks!

Comment: There are potentially a lot of things wrong with this code.  On the other hand, it might be just fine.  Without context, it is impossible to provide a reasonable answer to this question.

Comment: Value is initialized when you compile with debug enabled.

Comment: @James: Maybe on some implementations, maybe not. That's a terrible excuse in any case, though.

Comment: **Type limits: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271076/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-a-long-in-c/271132#271132** For the inevitable train-wreck of types, sizes, ranges, and bits.

Comment: Apart from using an uninitialized variable, there is potential issue of promoting an int literal to a long literal, in which case, you end up with and-ing 0xffffffff (i.e. do nothing).

Comment: I deleted my answer about sign extension because it's wrong.  I suspect it's what the interviewer is looking for, but if the interviewer is looking for that, they're wrong too.

Comment: One can be "experienced in C++" and never used the bitwise operators.  C++ is such a big language that supports so many programming paradigms that (beyond "Hello World!" type things) I'm not sure it's possible to definitively determine if one has experience based on 1 question.

Comment: If there is unspecified stuff between the declaration and the and-with statement, I would assume the stuff initializes 'value'.  Given that, I would consider the code as the most straightforward way to mask off all but the bottom 16 bits of 'value'.  There are some interesting caveats with the signed/unsigned behavior of hex constants (e.g. the effects of comparing 0xFFFF to -2 or -200000 on a 16-bit machine) but this code does not encounter them.

Comment: Axn: `0xffff` will *not* be promoted to `0xffffffff` in any case - `0xffff` is always the same as `65535`, which means that the constant has type `unsigned int` if `int` is only 16 bits.  It will be remain `0xffff` / `65535` when promoted to a `long`.

Comment: @caf:  `0xffff` and `65535` are not exactly the same, however.  If `int` has a width of 16 bits, the former is of type `unsigned int` while the latter is of type `long`.  They do always have the same value, of course.

Comment: @Josh: it's using bit-wise operation. I don't know about you, but that's always a red herring for me...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Several answers here state that if an `int` has a width of 16 bits, `0xFFFF` is negative.  This is not true.  `0xFFFF` is never negative.

A hexadecimal literal is represented by the first of the following types that is large enough to contain it:  `int`, `unsigned int`, `long`, and `unsigned long`.

If `int` has a width of 16 bits, then `0xFFFF` is larger than the maximum value representable by an `int`.  Thus, `0xFFFF` is of type `unsigned int`, which is guaranteed to be large enough to represent `0xFFFF`.

When the usual arithmetic conversions are performed for evaluation of the `&`, the `unsigned int` is converted to a `long`.  The conversion of a 16-bit `unsigned int` to `long` is well-defined because every value representable by a 16-bit `unsigned int` is also representable by a 32-bit `long`.

There's no sign extension needed because the initial type is not signed, and the result of using `0xFFFF` is the same as the result of using `0xFFFFL`.

Alternatively, if `int` is wider than 16 bits, then `0xFFFF` is of type `int`.  It is a signed, but positive, number.  In this case both operands are signed, and `long` has the greater conversion rank, so the `int` is again promoted to `long` by the usual arithmetic conversions.

---

As others have said, you should avoid performing bitwise operations on signed operands because the numeric result is dependent upon how signedness is represented.

Aside from that, there's nothing particularly wrong with this code.  I would argue that it's a style concern that `value` is not initialized when it is declared, but that's probably a nit-pick level comment and depends upon the contents of the `//some stuff` section that was omitted.

It's probably also preferable to use a fixed-width integer type (like `uint32_t`) instead of `long` for greater portability, but really that too depends on the code you are writing and what your basic assumptions are.

Comment: You're right.  I bet an interviewer who asked this question would be shown up as wrong.  :-)

Comment: @Omnifarious:  That's likely.  Either way, I think it's a terrible interview question.

Comment: Note though that the numeric result of doing bitwise operations on signed operands only varies if negative numbers / the sign bit are involved.  For example, in this case, if `value` is positive then the result is well-defined (the same as `value % 65536`), but if `value` is negative then there are three possible results.

Comment: Out of interest, what are the three possible results `caf` mentions?

Answer (score 3):

I think depending on the size of a long the 0xffff literal (-1) could be promoted to a larger size and being a signed value it will be sign extended, potentially becoming 0xffffffff (still -1).

Comment: `0xFFFF` is never negative.  I've posted an answer with details.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I'll assume it's because there's no predefined size for a long, other than it must be at least as big as the preceding size (int).  Thus, depending on the size, you might either truncate value to a subset of bits (if long is more than 32 bits) or overflow (if it's less than 32 bits).</strike>

Yeah, longs (per the spec, and thanks for the reminder in the comments) must be able to hold at least -2147483647 to 2147483647 (LONG_MIN and LONG_MAX).

Comment: You mean if it's less/greater than 16 bits?

Comment: +1 - I didn't think about the fact that the size of long can change while looking at this question.

Comment: I thought it was just int that had an undefined size, long = 32bit, long long = 64bit. But ferenuff, one learns something every day :)

Comment: `long` is required to be at least 32bits

Comment: -1 While your first sentence is true, the rest of your answer doesn't follow.

Comment: -1 A `long` is guaranteed at least 32 bits, by reference to the C standard (where it follows from guaranteed value range). Hence there's nothing technically wrong with the statement. It masks all but the lower 16 bits of the value, that's all, and if that's the intention (and a value has been assigned) then the code is correct, and if that isn't the intention then the code is wrong. The interviewer doesn't know C++. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach - Is an int also required to be at least 32 bits by the standard?

Comment: @Omnifarious: no, `int` is just required to be at least 16 bits.

Comment: The standard (C) doesn't mandate bit sizes but it _does_ mandate minimum ranges. So a long must be (at minimum) 32 bits wide since it must hold from -2147483647 through 2147483647.

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach - So, in truth the code may not actually truncate the lower 16 bits because the 0xffff might be sign extended, as I state in my answer.  :-)

Comment: @pax: You're right on the first second, wrong on the second. It only needs to support ±32767, or 16-bits.

Comment: @GMan That is true for `int`, `long` has to be at least 32 bits.

Comment: @Let: Oh, I thought we were talking about `int` (and failed to even read the details.). Well that settles that then, my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

For one value isn't initialized before doing the and so I think the behaviour is undefined, value could be anything.

Comment: It's not undefined -- the content could be garbage but it can't (For example) format your hard drive.

Comment: @Billy: formally it can do the nasal daemons thing. but in practice, on 32-bit systems an indeterminate value of type `int` is just *some* `int` value. on a 64-bit system, + on some very archaic architectures, there may be checking and a trap. cheers,

Comment: @Alf: Yes, the actual **contents** of the variable are undefined. That does NOT mean that it is **undefined behavior**. If it was undefined behavior a conformant compiler could format your hard drive. Whereas in this case it's only allowed to put garbage into a single variable.

Comment: @Billy: It is indeed *undefined behavior* to read (perform an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on) an uninitialized variable. It can very well reformat your hard-drive. See §4.1.

Answer (score 0):

long type size is platform/compiler specific.

What you can here say is:

1. It is signed.
2. We can't know the result of value &= 0xFFFF; since it could be for example value &= 0x0000FFFF; and will not do what expected.

Comment: Again, `long` doesn't imply 4 bytes.  It only implies >= `sizeof(int)`

Comment: @Billy and @Charles: Julio didn't say four bytes. He implied that the size of `long` *can be* 32 bits (which might be 1, 2 or 4 bytes depending on `CHAR_BIT`). And minimum 32 bit size for `long` is guaranteed by the standard, so it can indeed be 32 bits. Cheers & hth.

Answer (score 0):

While one could argue that since it's not a buffer-overflow or some other error that's likely to be exploitable, it's a *style* thing and not a bug, I'm 99% confident that the answer that the question-writer is looking for is that `value` is operated on before it's assigned to. The value is going to be arbitrary garbage, and that's unlikely to be what was meant, so it's "potentially wrong".

Answer (score -1):

Using MSVC I think that the statement would perform what was most likely intended - that is: clear all but the least significant 16 bits of value, but I have encountered other platforms which would interpret the literal 0xffff as equivalent to (short)-1, then sign extend to convert to long, in which case the statement "value &= 0xFFFF" would have no effect.
"value &= 0x0FFFF" is more explicit and robust.