# C++ - Dynamic memory allocation required memory

Tags: c++, size, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, new-operator

If I want to allocate memory dynamically to an `int` object, I can do this:

`int *x = new int;`

In this case, I know that the heap reseves `4-bytes` of memory for an `int` object.

But, if I have a `user-defined` class (type) and wanted to allocate memory dynamically, as follows:

`Car *c = new Car;`

How can I know the required amount of memory to be reserved on the heap for a `Car` object?

Thanks.

Comment: @user588855 you need to know size of `c`'s memory size, or you are also interested in dynamic memory that Car's constructor can allocate?

Comment: [An `int` isn't necessarily four bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271076/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-a-long-in-c/271132#271132).

Answer (score 3):

That will be the `sizeof(Car)` bytes. Compiler will do this automatically, you need not do anything specific.

Comment: @Ashot Martirosyan: Still when you do `new` only `sizeof(pointer)` is allocated. So above statement is still correct. It will be *minimum* (as it might be padded) `sizeof(Car)` bytes. Having pointer to dynamic memory won't change anything.

Comment: when you are doing new you are calling constructor of Car, which can allocate dynamic memory. If asker mean only memory of Class itself, than your answer is correct.

Comment: @Ashot Martirosyan: As far as I see, that is the question. In my view OP is asking what happens when you do `new Car;` i.e. how does the compiler calculate how much memory to allocate.

Comment: @Ashot `new` calls the constructor, and the constructor does initialization. Any allocation done in the constructor has nothing to do with the size of `Car` since the `Car` has already been allocated...

Answer (score 2):

See [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/size_of_class_object.html) article for information about how the size of a class object is determined.  It's available to you programatically using:

```
size_t car_size = sizeof(Car);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`sizeof()`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/language/sizeof). Note that this value may be larger than expected for user-defined types due to memory padding and/or alignment.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the `sizeof` operator. The sizeof operator returns the size of your type in bytes, and is evaluated at compile time. This is particularly useful for `malloc` since malloc requires you to specify how many bytes you need to allocate. However, you are using C++ and `new` does this automatically for you.

The `sizeof` operator returns the type `size_t` which is found in `cstddef` or `stddef.h`

Example code:

`size_t size_in_bytes = sizeof(Car);`