# Representation of Long Integers

Tags: c++, types, size

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between an int and a long in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271076/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-a-long-in-c)

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(int) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(long int) << std::endl;
}
```

**Output:**

```
4
4
```

How is this possible?  Shouldn't `long int` be bigger in size than `int`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The guarantees you have are:

```
sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long)

sizeof(int)   * CHAR_BITS >= 16
sizeof(long)  * CHAR_BITS >= 32
CHAR_BITS                 >= 8
```

All these conditions are met with:

```
sizeof(int)  == 4
sizeof(long) == 4
```

Answer (score 2):

C++ langauge never guaranteed or required `long int` to be *bigger* than `int`. The only thing the language is promising is that `long int` is *not smaller* than `int`. In many popular implementations `long int` has the same size as `int`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the language and the platform. In ISO/ANSI C, For example, the long integer type is 8 bytes in 64-bit system Unix, and 4 bytes in other os/platforms.

Answer (score 1):

No. It's valid under the C standard for `int` to be the same size as `short int`, for `int` to be the same size as `long int`, for `int` not to be the same as either `long int` or `short int`, or even for all three to be the same size. On 16-bit machines it was common for `sizeof(int)` == `sizeof(short int)` == 2 and `sizeof(long int)` == 4, but the most common arrangement on 32-bit machines is `sizeof(int)` == `sizeof(long int)` == 4 and `sizeof(short int)` == 2. And on 64-bit machines you may find `sizeof(short int)` == 2, `sizeof(int)` == 4, and `sizeof(long int)` == 8.

Answer (score 0):

See http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/163333-sizeof-int-sizeof-long-int.

> No nothing is wrong. The size of data-types is generally hardware dependant (exception being char which is always 1 register wide). In gcc/Unix, int and long int both require 4 bytes. You can also try sizeof(long long int) and see the results and sizeof(short int).

Comment: Why do they require 4 bytes on Unix?