# C# equivalent for C++ "signed long int"

Tags: c#, marshalling, managed

I import a C++ dll into a C# project and, on a x64 machine, on debug mode, PInvoke complains that managed signature does not match the unmanaged target signature.

C++:

```
void _Foo(signed long int x);
```

C#:

```
[DllImport("foo.dll", EntryPoint="_Foo"]
public static extern void Foo(int x)
```

Replacing `int` in the C# code with `IntPtr` or `Int64` didn't solve the problem.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the exact error coming from pinvoke?  I think you're asking the wrong question here (I answered the question you asked but it's not going to help you).

Comment: Exactly Larry, I had a similar answer yet got marked down. >:(

Comment: My best guess is that this is actually compiled as 32-bit.  The EntryPoint property is wrong, it is __Foo (two underscores).  CallingConvention is missing too.  Not posting the *exact* error message was a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

It's System.Int32.  Also known as "int".

Comment: And yes, I read the part of the question that said that pinvoke complained about the signature mismatch.  If it complained, it's not complaining about the "int" part.

Comment: No - the C# "long" type is System.Int64. But he asked about the C++ long type which is a 32bit number (on most 32bit operating systems and all Windows systems).

Answer (score 0):

A `long int` in C++ == `int` in C#. Both are 4 bytes long. A `long long` in C++ == `long` in C#. (8 bytes).

As Larry above says, if it is picking up a type mismatch, it is not because of the int.

Comment: Why has this been marked down?! It is stating fact and points towards a different problem than the one assumed by the original poster. Mark downs should be accompanied by a mandatory comment. So frustrating.

Comment: I was getting to it :). Had to walk out of the office. It's because of your over-zealous claim that in C++ a long int is 4 bytes long. This is not the case. until you attach a specific platform to those numbers, this answer is not a "fact" and is indeed wrong.

Comment: Strange I always went under the assumption that it was always the same. Can't find any evidence to go against this but did find http://jk-technology.com/c/inttypes.html and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz(v=VS.100).aspx which both define a long int as 4 bytes.

Comment: If you're talking specifically about MS's C++ compiler documented on MSDN, then your statement is correct. If you say "C++" in the general term, you're wrong. You just need more specificity.

Comment: The other document doesn't specify which target platform it is talking about. And various other sources I have searched for also do not specify particular platforms, but I'll bow to your greater knowledge, I am a .Net developer and only have brief crossings with C++. Maybe you could cite some documentation which states differences of types across platforms?

Comment: I don't have access to the C++ standard, but it's in there. You don't get size promises of the nature that you get in Java and .NET. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271076/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-a-long-in-c/271132#271132 for an example.

Comment: Actually, read the document that you posted http://jk-technology.com/c/inttypes.html#int. It makes my point.