# Difference between memory of int type in C++ and C#

Tags: c#, c++, types

In `C#` int type variable take `4 byte` memory and in `c++` it take `2 byte` memory. Even in `c++ short` and `int` both take `2 byte` memory and `long` takes `4 byte`. And in C# the short and int just take 4 byte. Why is this difference of memory in both languages while both follow the OOPS?

Comment: beacuse that's how they are defined...

Comment: 'In C# int type variable take 4 byte memory and in c++ it take 2 byte': ints in c++ are often 4 bytes...  It's somewhat implementation specific.

Comment: [size of int, long, etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/size-of-int-long-etc) and [What is the difference between an int and a long in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271076/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-a-long-in-c/271132#271132)

Comment: What compiler are you using? Typically int is 4 bytes.

Comment: @Code Monkey: Pretty sure Turbo C++ used to have a 2 byte int... but it's been a while.

Comment: Sizes of integer types in C++ aren't so well defined that you seem to think.  There is a minimum but no maximum.  It is quite common to have int as a 32 bits type; there have been implementations where all types were 64 bits.

Comment: Indeed. I think you could, theoretically, have a legal C++ implementation where char, short, int, long, long long etc were all the same size. (And that size could, theoretically, be 9 bits or 13 bits or 25 bits without breaking spec.)

Answer (score 2):

An integer that takes 2 bytes can only have 65536 different values. They are just different views on the same thing, this would mean that in the implementation of C++ that you are using:

```
          C++          C#
1 byte    byte         byte
2 bytes   int/short    short
4 bytes   long         int
```

etc.

C++ is not more memory efficient on these numbers, the keywords just have different meaning.

Answer (score 2):

In *C#*:

- int is always *System.Int32*
- short is always *System.Int16*
- long is always *System.Int64*

And this is because *C#* is compiled to *CIL*.

In *C++* it depends on the architecture:

On 32-bit:

- int and long are usually 4-bytes
- short is usually 2-bytes

On 64-bit depends on the platform but I haven't ever seen 2-byte int in *C++*.

The main difference is compilation into native code in C++ and compilation into CIL in C#.

Comment: In the olden days, there were 16 bit CPUs... and compilers to match.

Answer (score 1):

On platforms where C# has a 4 byte int, C++ has that as well.

The difference is that C++ can also run on different platforms, with other sizes for the built in types.

Comment: Assuming 'platforms' refers to OS, this answer seems wrong.  This http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/run-turbo-c-ide-in-windows-7-with-fullscreen/e68e985b-af44-4b2f-b268-78251ab2bed5 suggests you can run Turbo c++ on windows 7.  This http://www.ousob.com/ng/borcpp/nga434c.php suggests that for turbo c++, the size of an int is 2 bytes.  The C# equivalent for windows 7 would be 4 bytes.  I think it's dangerous to suggest a correlation between the int sizes between the two languages.

Comment: :-) If I add a VM to Windows, I can run anything. The point was rather that C# only runs on .NET, so it only needs to have one size.

Comment: 'I can run anything'... Now that's a bold statement!  But I take your point, .Net's your platform :)