# size of int variable

Tags: c, int, 32bit-64bit, processor

How the size of int is decided?

Is it true that the size of int will depend on the processor. For 32-bit machine, it will be 32 bits and for 16-bit it's 16.

On my machine it's showing as 32 bits, although the machine has 64-bit processor and 64-bit Ubuntu installed.

Comment: it also depends upon the compiler, because C doesn't speak about the exact size of the int.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/size-of-int-long-etc

Answer (score 9):

It depends on the implementation. The only thing the C standard guarantees is that

```
sizeof(char) == 1
```

and

```
sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)
```

and also some representable minimum values for the types, which imply that `char` is at least 8 bits long, `int` is at least 16 bit, etc.

So it must be decided by the implementation (compiler, OS, ...) and be documented.

Comment: I came across a compiler with a `short long`. `int` was 16 bits, and `short long` was 24.

Comment: @detly The creators of that compiler certainly had a sense of humour.

Comment: Yeah, the size of `double` was given as "24 or 32". This was for a microprocessor.

Comment: @detly you mean microcontroller.

Comment: These guarantees are incomplete. Also must be that `CHAR_BIT` is at least 8, `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT` must at least be 16, etc. [See here for more](http://stackoverflow.com/a/271132/87234).

Comment: @GManNickG Correct, fixed.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the standard imposes requirements on the *ranges* of the integer types, not their sizes. In the presence of padding bits, it's possible to have `sizeof (long) < sizeof (int)`, if `int` has more padding bits than `long`. (Such an implementation is unlikely.)

Comment: Also, with the current standards, `long long` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the compiler.

For eg : Try an old turbo C compiler & it would give the size of 16 bits for an int because the word size (The size the processor could address with least effort) at the time of writing the compiler was 16.

Comment: To be (extremely) pedantic; it would give `2` for `sizeof int`, and there are `CHAR_BIT` bits in a byte.  `sizeof` returns the number of bytes, and there need not be 8 bits in a byte.

Answer (score 2):

Making `int` as wide as possible is not the best choice.  (The choice is made by the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) designers.)

A 64bit architecture like x86-64 can efficiently operate on `int64_t`, so it's natural for `long` to be 64 bits.  (Microsoft kept `long` as 32bit in their x86-64 ABI, for various portability reasons that make sense given the existing codebases and APIs.  This is basically irrelevant because portable code that actually cares about type sizes should be using `int32_t` and `int64_t` instead of making assumptions about `int` and `long`.)

Having `int` be `int32_t` actually makes for better, more efficient code in many cases.  An array of `int` use only 4B per element has only half the cache footprint of an array of `int64_t`.  Also, specific to x86-64, 32bit operand-size is the default, so 64bit instructions need an extra code byte for a REX prefix.  So code density is better with 32bit (or 8bit) integers than with 16 or 64bit.  (See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) wiki for links to docs / guides / learning resources.)

If a program requires 64bit integer types for correct operation, it won't use `int`.  (Storing a pointer in an `int` instead of an `intptr_t` is a bug, and we shouldn't make the ABI worse to accommodate broken code like that.)  A programmer writing `int` probably expected a 32bit type, since most platforms work that way.  (The standard of course only guarantees 16bits).

**Since there's no expectation that `int` will be 64bit in general (e.g. on 32bit platforms), and making it 64bit will make some programs slower (and almost no programs faster), `int` is 32bit in most 64bit ABIs.**

Also, there needs to be a name for a 32bit integer type, for `int32_t` to be a `typedef` for.

Answer (score 0):

It is depends on the primary compiler.
if you using turbo c means the integer size is 2 bytes.
else you are using the GNU gccompiler means the integer size is 4 bytes.
it is depends on only implementation in C compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The size of integer is basically depends upon the `architecture` of your system.
Generally if you have a `16-bit` machine then your `compiler` will must support a int of `size 2 byte.`
If your system is of 32 bit,then the compiler must support for 4 byte for integer.

In more details,

- The concept of `data bus` comes into picture yes,16-bit ,32-bit means nothing but the `size of data bus` in your system.
- The data bus size is required for to determine the size of an integer because,The purpose of data bus is to  provide data to the processor.The max it can provide to the processor at a single fetch is important and this max size is preferred by the compiler to give a data at time.
- Basing upon this data bus size of your system the compiler is
  designed to provide max size of the data bus as the size of integer.

> ```
> x06->16-bit->DOS->turbo c->size of int->2 byte
> x306->32-bit>windows/Linux->GCC->size of int->4 byte
> ```

Comment: thanx for the info, what's about on the 64 bit>Linux...in 64 bit systems the data bus will be of size 64 bits, there also the compiler is showing 4 bytes

Comment: The concept is,in a 64 bit machine the compiler can support upto 8-byte data that doesn't mean it can't support 4 byte.Simply speaking lower system can compatible with the higher systems so,the system is 64-bit but the compiler is supporting upto 32-bit.so it is showing 4-byte,check for the latest compiler version.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.  `int` size depends on the compiler size.
For 16 bit integer the range of the integer is between -32768 to 32767.  For  32 & 64 bit compiler it will increase.