# Factors influencing the size of primitives,their range and running of binaries on different platforms

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, operating-system, primitive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does the size of an int depend on the compiler and/or processor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331751/does-the-size-of-an-int-depend-on-the-compiler-and-or-processor)

I am using `64 bit` OS *(windows 7)* and using `Dev C++` compiler *(32 bit)* . I also use `Microsoft Visual C++` *(32 bit)* .

I am confused over the size of primitives. *(int,char,short etc)* 
 Please address my few questions :

•   On what does the size of these data types depend ? I have heard that the sizes vary with the kind of processor , operating system , compiler. Is that so ? If yes , please explain how do they vary.

•   If I am using 64 bit OS and 32 bit compiler , the binary that will be produced will be compatible for both 32 OS and 64 OS  ? Please address this issue properly and give a clear and a precise answer.

•   What are the factors influencing the binary produced on a particular platform ?

•   Suppose a binary is produced with a 32 bit compiler on 32 bit linux , will it be any different on 32 bit windows ?

•   How is the range of a data type like `int` defined ?  On what factors does it depend ? Earlier I read that it is `32767` but while using Microsoft visual C++ it is greater than `32767` . Is the range totally dependent on compiler or it also depends upon the Operating system or what type of processor it is ?

•   Let there be a program :

```
#include<iostream.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
 int x;
 cout<<sizeof(x);
}
```

While using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 (32 bit) on 32 bit windows , it prints `4` as the answer. Will this result vary if I run it on 64 bit platform ? In any case give a proper reason with the answer.

Comment: **@peopleWhoHaveVotedToClose** There are certain questions to be addressed. It may not be the exact duplicate.

Comment: you can check as follows:


[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739693/size-of-int-variable/][1]

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331751/does-the-size-of-an-int-depend-on-the-compiler-and-or-processor][2] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739693/size-of-int-variable/
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331751/does-the-size-of-an-int-depend-on-the-compiler-and-or-processor

Comment: @pradipta did a grt job..but it will be good...if u try to give the original answer instead of duplicate questions