# Best pratice for typedef of uint32

Tags: typedef, uint32

On a system where both long and int is 4 bytes which is the best and why?

```
typedef unsigned long u32;
```

or

```
typedef unsigned int u32;
```

note: uint32_t is not an option

Comment: Is it C or C++ or some othe language? Add the tag.

Comment: Can you explain why Standard C and Standard C++ are "not an option" ? You might need to mention which platform and compiler you are using, if they are not standards-compliant.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays every platform has `stdint.h` or its C++ equivalent `cstdint` which define `uint32_t`.  Please use the standard type rather than creating your own.

- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7999959899/basedefs/stdint.h.html
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874765.aspx

Comment: Thanks but uint32_t is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

The size will be the same between both, so it depend only on your use.
If you need to store decimal values, use long.

A better and complete answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271076/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-a-long-in-c/271132

Edit: I'm not sure about decimal with long, if someone can confirm, thanks.

Comment: Can't you store decimal values using long? That what I though, but I'm not used to deal with C++, so I'm not sure at all. If you can't then tell me, I'll update the answer. I still think the link is the best explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said the standard `uint32_t` is not an option, using `long` and `int` are both correct on 32-bit machines, I'll say

```
typedef unsigned int u32;
```

is a little better, because on two popular 64-bit machine data models (LLP64 and LP64), `int` is still 32-bit, while `long` could be 32-bit or 64-bit. See [64-bit data models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models)