# long float c++ visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, floating-point

I've started to learn C++ with Stroustrup's C++ programming book - data types. It says that for floating point types language have float, double, long double types. But this program runs good for me:

```
long float float2{ 5.0F };
cout << float2 << endl;

cout << "size of long float: " << sizeof(long float) << endl; // 8

std::cout << "min long float value: " << (long float)std::numeric_limits<long float>::min() << std::endl; // 2.22507e-308
std::cout << "max long float value: " << (long float)std::numeric_limits<long float>::max() << std::endl << std::endl; // 1.79769e+308
```

i.e. the same as double. So what's the difference? As far as I knew before there's no such type - ***long float***. Is it the microsoft compiler feature? Is it a new standard?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271076/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-a-long-in-c

Comment: @ali786: That question is about `int` and `long` types. What does it have to do with this question?

Comment: Yes you are correct, but In answer one of the user has given good explaination of int and long. In windows both will have 4 bytes of size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So what's the difference?

`double` is a standard type; `long float` is not. For example, GCC rejects it: http://ideone.com/0pIhgK.

> As far as I knew before there's no such type - `long float`.

Not in standard C++, no.

> Is it the microsoft compiler feature?

Looks like it. That compiler is somewhat notorious for its language "extensions". I believe it has an option to disable (at least some of) them; it would be a good idea to do that, if you want to learn portable C++.

> Is it a new standard?

There's no mention of it in C++11, or the [latest draft of C++14](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3797.pdf). The floating point types are specified in 3.9.1/8:

> There are three *ﬂoating point types*: `float`, `double`, and `long double`.

Comment: Thank you. I found that there's warning in my project:  
warning C4215: nonstandard extension used. And I found this page:  
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00yasssw.aspx. But setting option to /Za allows for compiling anyway, i.e. there's no compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

You should be carefull using "long" because it takes more bytes, like an Integer is 4 bytes, an float is 16 bytes. and not sure if you have to use long for a number like "5.0f".