# Does type conversion happen if assigning a number to a long type without postfix "L"

Tags: c++, int, long-integer, type-conversion

My question is that if the following assignment in (1) involves type convernsion, i.e., from int to long?

```
(1)
    long i=0;
    ....
    i =2; 
(2)
    long i=0;
     .....
    i = 2L
```

Comment: This might be worth reading: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271076/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-a-long-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it involves conversion. But with a literal like this, the conversion will normally happen at compile time, so appending the `L` won't make any real difference unless you find the code more readable with the `L` there (I normally don't).

There are a few cases where you can append a suffix to get a result that's actually different from what you'd get without the suffix, but the ones you've shown don't fall into this category.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, yes, it's a conversion. The type of an integer literal without a suffix is `int` as long as the literal's value can indeed by represented by an `int`. This is certainly the case for the values `0` and `2`. So, in `i = 2`, the right-hand side is `int`, and must be converted to `long`

However, it's only a conversion by the rules of the language. The compiler is undoubtedly going to generate code that directly sets the value of `i` to 2, rather than code that stores 2 in an `int` variable and then performs a run-time conversion.