# User32 SetWindowLong accepts int instead long

Tags: c#, user32

When I try to call a function from User32.dll in C#, SetWindowLong, nothing happens. I know why, but I don't know how to "repair" this.
Here's a piece of code.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern long GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern long SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
const int WS_EX_TOPMOST = 0x00000008;
const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
public static bool IsWindowTopMost(int id)
{
    return (GetWindowLong(GetHWNDById(id), GWL_EXSTYLE) & WS_EX_TOPMOST) == WS_EX_TOPMOST;
}
public static void SetAlwaysOnTop(int id)
{
    IntPtr hWnd = GetHWNDById(id);
    long actuallyStyle = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_TOPMOST;
    SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, (int)actuallyStyle));
}
```

IsWindowTopMost works fine, but SetAlwaysOnTop does not. After a quick examination of the code, I found something interesting. Variable "actuallyStyle" after GetWindowLong is equal to 4295295232, after OR operation 4295295240. Here is the problem, function SetWindowLong accepts as dwNewLong a Integer. When I change int with long in the definition of SetWindowLong, pinvoke throws an error, because "unmatched function and target function".

How does it get around?

Comment: Always go to pinvoke.net when using dll functions.  See : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowLong.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to put a window always on top is to use the [SetWindowPos function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx). Problem is most likely that `SetWindowLong` just sets a variable, but `SetWindowPos` actually notifies the window manager to do the needed redrawing, so use that instead.

Now about the question title, both `SetWindowLong` and `GetWindowLong` must be declared as `int`, not as `long`.
This follows 2 reasons are for that. First, the differences between C and C#. The entire Windows API documentation is defined in C terms, [where long means 32 bits signed integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/271076/2557263), but C# threats `long` as a 64 bits signed integer, hence giving the error you're getting. Functions using 64 bits are declared in the API documentation as `long long`.
Another reason for that difference is historical. Both functions where created in the 16 bits era of Windows, where `int` was 16 bits and `long` 32 bits. The `int` type was expanded latter on, but `long` remained as it was. The name wasn't changed to keep compatibility.