# (C++) Visual Studio gives different outputs as other compilers for simple array sum problem

Tags: c++

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

long ar[10];
int arraySize;

long aVeryBigSum(long arr[]) {
    long total = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < arraySize; x++) {
    
        total += ar[x];
    }
    return total;
}

int main() {
    
    cin >> arraySize;
    for (int x = 0; x < arraySize; x++) {

        cin >> ar[x];   
    }
    cout << aVeryBigSum(ar);

return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
5
1000000001 1000000002 1000000003 1000000004 1000000005
```

Visual Studio output:

```
705032719
```

Online IED output(correct):

```
5000000015
```

I have no idea what to try in this situation as different compilers are giving me different answer. Assuming its something to do with data type long

Comment: Visual Studio's long is always 32-bit. You get signed integer overflow and undefined behavior. Try `long long` type.

Comment: A long in MSVC is only 32 bits. Even with x64. Same as an int. Use long long

Comment: long is used incorrectly here.  The length is only guaranteed to be 32 bits (but a compiler is allowed to use more),   "long - target type will have width of at least 32 bits.   long long - target type will have width of at least 64 bits " - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/271092/5282154) which describes msvc and clang long size differences

Comment: I don't know why someone gave you a -1.  It's not common knowledge that MSVC's `long` is a different size than everybody else's.

Comment: You pass array to your function then simply ignore it and use global array and size, you better pass them. But even better to use `std::vector` here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `long int` is likely a signed 32-bit integer type, which means the largest positive integer it can store is 2,147,483,647, but your sum adds up to 5,000,000,015. Because this is larger, integer overflow has occurred.

Replace the `long int` type with `long long int`. Or to make the sizes of the types more explicit, include `<cstdint>` and use `int64_t`.

Comment: Notice that `5000000015 & 0x7fffffff` is `705032719`.

Answer (score 1):

but the limits of the "long" is -2,147,483,648~2,147,483,647;
you can use`std::numeric_limits<long>::max();`to get the limit.
the value total has exceeded its limits since the third addition,so the outcome was not as your expectation.
change the long to "long long" you'll get the correct answer.

```
long long aVeryBigSum(long arr[]) {
long long total = 0;

for (int x = 0; x < arraySize; x++) {

    total += ar[x];
}
return total;
```

}

as to other IDEs, maybe they do some optimization?

Answer (score 1):

this problem is associated with specifical compilers and machines. c++ standard just promises that the length of int is not shorter than short, the length of long is not shorter than int, the length of long long is not shorter than long.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).